# Page '312e8a59-2712-48a1-863e-0ef4e67961fc' not found using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio

When I click on the home-icon of Team Explorer, I get the following error:

> Page '312e8a59-2712-48a1-863e-0ef4e67961fc' not found instead of all the options.

I have this error since I reinstalled the Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate trial and installed the Visual Studio 2012 Premium edition. Repair and reinstall didn't work out.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

To fix this, run this from the Visual Studio command prompt as administrator:

```
devenv /setup
```

It will not mess up your environment, and you can just continue to use Visual Studio afterwards was my experience.

Comment: solution here http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/768836/page-312e8a59-2712-48a1-863e-0ef4e67961fc-not-found-vs-2012-premium

Comment: This just happened to me after I installed TFS Sidekicks.  Running "devenv /setup" took just about a minute and completely solved the problem.

Comment: Happened for me after installing the latest version of Xaml Spy.  This command fixed it.

Comment: Happened to me after installing codemaid on VS2013. Thanks heaps for the fix.

Comment: Happened for me when applying the latest SSDTSetup.exe as advertised from VS2013. This solved it. Thanks.

Comment: Phew, that saved me from re-install

Comment: Worked for me after a update messed up my VS :-) Thanks

Comment: happened to me when I upgrade nuget pcks, command fixed, thanks!

Comment: I'll continue the endless list of reasons of this issue =). For me it happened after the new year and simultaneous expiration of Telerik Dev Craft. Not sure which of those is the exact reason. Solution worked, thanks.

Comment: Typical location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

Comment: Stupidly enough, running `devenv.exe /setup` gives a completely different behaviour to running `devenv /setup`.

Comment: Had the issue after installing VS 2015 pro update 1, in cohabitation with VS 2013 Ultimate. Issue solved. :o

Comment: I had the issue after installing VS 2015 Pro Update 1 - command above didn't help - not even multiple times, not even after restart

Comment: As noted in an answer bellow, you may need to run the Developer Command Prompt item and not the others. Using that command prompt item seems to have fixed the issue on my work machine, which is running VS 2013 Ultimate, despite the command prompt window indicating the operation couldn't be completed as I didn't have the right access level to run it.

Comment: Worked in 2017 as well!

Answer (score 32):

I had the same error in Visual Studio 2013 and tried:

*Control Panel* → *Programs* .... → *Visual Studio* → *Repair*

*It did not work*

```
devenv /setup
```

*It did not work*

```
devenv /clearcache
devenv /updateconfiguration
```

*It did not work*

And then THE solution:

- *Close all Visual Studio instances
- Delete the %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache folder
- Start Visual Studio

It is explained in more detail in this blog post: *[When the EditorPackage does not load correctly](http://www.rajapet.com/2014/02/when-the-editorpackage-does-not-load-correctly.html)*

Comment: This page is also usefull: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1123745/setsite-failed-for-package-microsoft-visualstudio-editor-implementation-editorpackage

Comment: The devenv setup did not do it for me... simply Repair was enough

Comment: Nothing else worked for me but renaming the ComponentModelCache folder did. Thanks.

Comment: I had this same issue, different package id, and renaming the folder worked for me. thanks.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me. Thanks!

Comment: This happened because I installed both Git and Visual Studio Code on top of Visual Studio 2013 (Windows 8 OS).  This fix worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

I had this error on Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate - Windows 8:

[image: Team Explorer Error]

And I solved this problem running this command:

```
X64: devenv.exe /resetskippkgs
x86: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /resetskippkgs
```

Comment: Another error show up: "Invalid Command Line. Unknown Switch : resetskippkgs)."

Comment: Worked for me even after the others like denenv /setup didn't. Afterwards, I could open VS without it

Answer (score 3):

> I faced similar issue. Running `devenv /setup` did not help me.

Just wanted to share some additional info:

At first, `devenv /setup` did not help me as well.  Then I realized that I was using the wrong Visual Studio command prompt version.

Make sure that you run `devenv /setup` for the appropriate Visual Studio version.

For example:  for Visual Studio 2013, use the "Developer Command Prompt" under the Visual studio 2013 "Visual Studio Tools" folder.

*And like it stated in the selected answer, run as administrator.

Comment: Just ran into the same issue on my work machine running VS 2013 Ultimate, and running the Developer Command Prompt item seems to have worked, despite it telling me, "The operation cannot be completed. Access is denied." VS is opening projects and connecting to TFS without issues for the time being. Issue cropped up after some kind of forced system restart I wasn't made aware of.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the suggested command: **devenv /setup**. It didn´t work for me. (Visual Studio 2015)

Then after that I tried something different:

-> Run Visual studio as administrator, after ran the command.

**Then the problem was solved.**

Answer (score 1):

Running Visual Studio as administrator resolves this for me.

Answer (score 0):

After I reinstalled my Visual Studio 2012 Trial, I've never deleted the documents directory. In this directory there were some backup files. This maybe have caused the problem.

After deleting this directory and installing Visual Studio 2012 Premium again the problem was solved.

Comment: I had the same exact issue. Filips solution worked for me and was far less tedious than uninstalling, reinstalling, pulling all projects back down from TFS.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. Running **devenv /setup** did not help me.

I found *[Fixing 312e8a59-2712-48a1-863e-0ef4e67961fc-not-found-vs-2012](http://hjerpbakk.com/blog/2014/7/25/no-content-in-solution-explorer-using-visual-studio-201)*. This link suggests that I might have recently installed some Visual Studio extensions, which might have corrupted the Visual Studio maintained cache. I uninstalled a couple of the latest Visual Studio extensions, and it solved the issue after Visual Studio's restart. Visual Studio is able to connect with TFS :-).

One can find Visual Studio extensions at menu *Tools* → *"Extensions and Updates...". Go to the *"All"* section under *Installed* section. It will show all Visual Studio extensions.

Comment: The link is broken (404).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, and then I tried running "devenv /setup" and no good result. That's was because you don't not trying with specific version Visual Studio command prompt. I then opened the command prompt for the specific version "Visual Studio 2013", and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue in Visual Studio 2013. I renamed `ComponentModelCache` to `ComponentModelCache2`, and it fixed it.

```
C:\Users\{..}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache
```