# How can I fix the Microsoft Visual Studio error: "package did not load correctly"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2017

I installed Visual Studio 2012 and [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Home/Mission.xml) 13.1. As Visual Studio started, it generated an error shown by this attached image,

> The 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage' package did not load correctly.
>
> The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more information by examining the file 'C:\Users\must\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ActivityLog.xml'.
>
> Continue to show this error message?

[image: Microsoft Visual Studio - The 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage' package did not load correctly.]

This error also appears in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Read that error carefully: "You can get more information by examining the file ..." - what does that file say?

Comment: @fvu Activity-Log file opening error generated.

Comment: One thing to check before doing deeper analysis - "Is there enough free space on the disk"?

Comment: FYI: I had same problem in VS Pro 15.7.x - solution from @dinesh solved it for me.

Comment: UPDATE: Opened a different project today (1 day after my prior comment above) and received the same error again.  Followed the steps in solution from @dinesh below, and error went away.  Don't know if it was the steps, or simply opening Visual Studio a second time.

Comment: the same issue with VS 2022, only when I run without admin right. No solution until now.

Answer (score 567):

I started to see this on a fresh Windows and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate with Update 2 installation (although others have also reported it on Updates 3 and 4, as well as the Professional version).

To resolve the problem, close all Visual Studio instances, then delete all files in the following folder:

Visual Studio 2013

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache
```

It worked fine for me. Thanks to [this article](http://limzhenghong.wordpress.com/2013/11/10/visual-studio-pastejson-jsonpackage-did-not-load-correctly/).

Visual Studio 2015

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
```

Visual Studio 2017

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_xxxx\ComponentModelCache
```

Visual Studio 2019

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16_xxxx\ComponentModelCache
```

Visual Studio 2022

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17_xxxx\ComponentModelCache
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue in VS 2015 but there doesn't appear to be any `ComponentModelCache` folder though. Perhaps it goes by a different name in newer versions of Visual Studio?

Comment: @jpierson yes the folder `ComponentModelCache` for VS 2015 can be found in the folder: `14.0`. The full path is as follows: `C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache`

Comment: I'm having this problem on my fresh install of Visual Studio 2017... and again, the folder structure is not the same!

Comment: Have added folder that was created for VS 2017, might want to try and see.

Comment: The following Powershell command will delete all directories within `%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio`  where the directory name ends with "cache": `get-childitem -Directory "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\microsoft\visualstudio" -Include *cache -Recurse | remove-item -Recurse -Verbose`

Comment: does not help to me in VS 2017 unfortunatelly

Comment: Upvoted you a few years ago, 2018 we meet again with the same issue in VS2017. It's still working, thanks.

Comment: One thing to note, if you always run VS as admin and still see the error after deleting the cache files, close all VS instances, delete cache files again, then run VS WITHOUT running as admin and let it load up. Then close it and run it as admin again. This resolved the issue for me :)

Comment: I strongly recommend using the "Import/Export Settings Wizard" to export all environment settings prior to attempting this solution or any other on this page. I somehow managed to wipe out all of my user settings, but thankfully I had a backup that wasn't too old.

Comment: My error was "The 'formatter package' did not load correctly" and this solution fixed it.

Comment: Worked for Visual Studio 2019: %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16_xxxx

Comment: Didn't work for me. What did, is disabling the "GitHub extension for Visual Studio" component. I'm using VS 2019 Pro v6.6.5 with Preview Feature "New Git user experience" enabled. Apparently the two have a conflict. You can only use one or the other anyway, so I ditched the former.

Comment: Its worked for me :AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_4c254fc3\ComponentModelCache

Comment: i can confirm, this also works on Visual Studio 2022

Comment: It does not work for me with Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) 
Version 17.0.6

Comment: Work Visual Studio 2022 but need to open VS with administrator rights the next first time.

Answer (score 112):

I encountered this problem in Visual Studio 2017 (15.7.4). After trying various solutions, eventually this worked for me: close all Visual Studio instances, and run this from the command line (possibly with administrator rights):

```
devenv.exe /clearcache
devenv /updateconfiguration
```

Comment: This worked for me, I think there's an issue with one of the productivity power tools extensions after latest VS update

Comment: This worked for me and I ran VS 2015 command prompt in admin mode. +1

Comment: Be sure to start `Developer Command Prompt for VS {version}`. `devenv.exe` is most likely not known in your normal CMD (if you haven‘t added it to the path at least). This Developer Command Prompt takes care of that. It was installed with VS and was in the start menu in my case.

Comment: Does anyone know what `/updateconfiguration` does exactly?

Comment: This worked for me, I have VS2019. Emptying cache or rewriting roaming didn't work for me

Comment: Worked for me to fix the package loading errors after updating VS2019 to 16.8.1

Comment: Worked for me in VisualStudio 2019 - thanks a lot!

Comment: This solution worked for me with VS 2019, whereas the answer by "user_v" with more votes did not. In my case the package name was "MyPackage" for some reason.

Comment: Confirming that it worked for me too with Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.9.4.

Comment: Worked for me on VS 2019 v16.11.7

Comment: I messed around with my GAC because System.ValueTuple would not find the correct version, and broke VS in the process. This fixed it.

Comment: I was able to get things working for myself but all the projects in my solution are being marked as incompatible in the solution explorer

Comment: This worked for me on VS 2022 v17.4.4 - the `/clearcache` was quick but the `/updateconfiguration` to a bit of time. I then had to reload each of the projects in our solution.

Comment: Confirming that this worked for me on VS 2022 Community.

Comment: Still working on Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64 bits) - Versión 17.7.2

Comment: I encountered this issue again in VS2022 (October 2023 release). After trying _every single method in this thread_, the only solution for me was to add `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0.dll` in the GAC. See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574089/how-can-i-fix-the-microsoft-visual-studio-error-package-did-not-load-correctly/51588427#comment136297343_51588427) and related answer.

Answer (score 68):

- Close Visual Studio.
- Backup and delete the following path:

  `C:\Users\{your_username}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0`
- Restart Visual Studio as `Admin`. Otherwise, the `Roaming` folder can't be repaired by Visual Studio.

Comment: This worked with visual studio 2015 community edition also. The path changes to `C:\Users\{your_username}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0`, but it works just the same. Also, before opening visual studio, I ran the `devenv /setup` command suggested by @J-B

Comment: The solution proposed by @user_v is a little less abrasive, as it only deletes the problem folder not the whole thing.

Comment: It worked for me. But After deleting the mentioned files, I run `devenv /setup` command in `Command Prompt for VS2015`. It caused the deleted files to be created again. then I run the Visual Studio ;)

Comment: There was not a VisualStudio folder there for me (VS Pro 2017). I deleted `C:\Users\{your_username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_xxxx` and started in Administrator mode and it worked.

Comment: I was getting this with the "Roslyn" package in Visual Studio 2022.  None of the other solutions here worked.  This fixed it though

Answer (score 35):

Try `devenv /setup` on the Visual Studio Command Prompt with administrative rights.

I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. I tried the solution by Reza posted here, but it didn't work.

Eventually I couldn't close Visual Studio. It was showing a similar dialog when I tried to close, and it wasn't closing. I tried this:  *[Error message "No exports were found that match the constraint contract name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name)*. Neither.

I noticed a message in the Team Explorer window saying "Page '*somenumber*' cannot be found". I tried that way, and I found this answer: *[Page '312e8a59-2712-48a1-863e-0ef4e67961fc' not found using Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088826/page-312e8a59-2712-48a1-863e-0ef4e67961fc-not-found-using-visual-studio-2012)*. So I run `devenv /setup` on the Visual Studio Command Prompt with administrative rights.

It did the job, and everything is fine now.

Comment: Microsoft does not give lot of details of what `devenv /setup` does. Just that it is the last step of the installation process. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex6a2fad.aspx

Comment: Props for the link to the "constraint contract name" question. That's what actually fixed my issue. Thanks for including it.

Comment: In my case `devenv.exe /resetuserdata` helped. Note: it resets *ALL* user data.

Comment: I've just had the same issue with VS Professional 16.3.5 and following the instructions in the Error message "No exports were found that match the constraint contract name" link worked for me

Answer (score 19):

Solution for Visual Studio 2017:

Step 1: open Visual Studio cmd in administrator mode (see start menu item: *Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017* - Be sure to use: Run as administrator)

Step 2: change directory to the folder where Visual Studio 2017 is installed, for example:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise
```

(You can copy/paste this command to your cmd prompt. For Visual Studio Professional, the folder will be called "Professional" instead of "Enterprise", etc.)

Step 3: copy/paste the below command

```
gacutil -if Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0.dll
```

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>...

It will resolve the issue...

Otherwise, you can also add the following to the [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache) as above:

`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.9.0.dll`

`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.10.0.dll`

`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll`

`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.12.0.dll`

Additionally, some users have reported that it is beneficial to add:

`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0`

Comment: I have had several Visual Studio projects show this error, and each time I repeated the steps above to solve it.

Comment: This solved my problem. We just upgraded our source from 2015 with 4.6.2 to 2017 with 4.7.1. I just started getting this problem and this is the solution that worked for me. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me after trying everything else above. Thanks!

Comment: In 2019 you need to add `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.12.0.dll`

Comment: I tried 15+ solutions. Only this answer has some magic.

Comment: suddenly one of my solutions started to show "HtmlPackage" did not load correctly, and another similar solution did not.. adding to GAC solved it.. BUT WHY? *added: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0*

Comment: Did not work for me. Tried adding all the listed dlls plus the ones listed in the comments here.

Comment: @BoppityBop thank you! Adding `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0` worked!! I literally tried every single other answer in this SO thread! VS Community/Professional 2022, October 2023 release.

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar problem, and I went to *Control Panel* → *Programs* and repaired the Visual Studio installation. It worked for me.

Comment: Tried 2 of above solutions for the same error but for **SpecFlow** package, it did not work. **This worked for me**. The solutions I tried: 1: Removing [ComponentModelCache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23646013/1265945) 2: Removing [AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18800520/1265945)

Comment: You can't repair Visual Studio 2017 from Control Panel, you have to navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer` where you can find the `vs_installer.exe` file.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Try to remember the latest extension that you installed. I delete the latest extension from extensions and updates and restart Visual Studio. and the problem is solved. For me, the extension name is  **Productivity Power Tools**

Answer (score 3):

I had the pleasure of experiencing this random problem in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.

I tried every solution here, and it didn't work, including the Visual Studio repair (which takes a while). Several hours in, I thought maybe I should actually check the ActivityLog.xml file.

[image: ActivityLog.xml]

I uninstalled the offending extension from the 'Developer Command Prompt for VS2017' as an administrator since Visual Studio just freezed after open and nothing could be clicked.

Steps to uninstall - courtesy of [jessehouwing.net](https://jessehouwing.net/visual-studio-uninstall-extension-from-the-commandline/)

1. Find the vsix file you used to install the extension.
2. Open it in your favorite archiver (mine is [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip)).
3. Grab the extension's **Id** from the **Identity** node from the *extension.vsixmanifest.*
4. Run (in my case) `vsixinstaller /u:Microsoft.VisualStudio.LiveShare` to remove the extension.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue (*Tizen Project type package did not load correctly*) with Visual Studio 2017.

After trying all the answers above, and spending a few hours searching for a solution for the errors inside `ActivityLog.XML`, nothing worked for me.

Eventually, the solution was a Visual Studio **Repair**.

I assume that the repair process overrides some configurations that caused the problem.

[Repair Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2017) 
[Repair Visual Studio 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

Comment: This worked for me with VS 2019. I ran the repair process, rebooted, and the error went away.

Answer (score 2):

I also experienced this issue after installing Telerik Reporting. I was not able to launch any solution in Visual Studio 2013, nor could I close Visual Studio 2013.

After uninstalling the reporting package and deleting Local / Roaming AppData for Visual Studio 2012, the problem was fixed.

Comment: Got a heap of similar errors recently. I was evaluating DevExpress components during last three weeks. So I uninstalled DevExpress, the error messages are gone. Not sure if DevExpress caused the problem though

Comment: In my case I reinstalled devexpress and all worked ok after that

Answer (score 2):

In my case the error message is *"The 'IntelliCodeCppPackage' package did not load correctly"* (Visual Studio 2019):

[image: IntelliCodeCppPackage]

I solved this is issue with these steps;

- Disable the *[Visual Studio IntelliCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.VSIntelliCode)* extension
- Restart Visual Studio
- Enable that extension again

Answer (score 2):

I tried everything except the repair. I even did an update. This is what fixed it for me:

1. Open "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017" as Admin
2. CD into (your path may vary) `CD C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies`
3. Run command `gacutil -i Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll`
4. Restart Visual Studio

Comment: A much better version of this answer was already posted 2 years before this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51588427/3873799. Please do not add noise with redundant answers. This issue is already messy as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is the top SO result in google for this issue, I'm going to leave my fix here for VS 2022 when experiencing this issue. I found it is commonly caused by an extension issue. In my particular case TypeScript Definition Generator was causing the issue and removing the extension solved it. To find which extension could be causing the issue, run VS with the `/Log` command line switch.

i.e.: `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /Log`

After the error occurs, close VS and locate ActivityLog.xml found at `%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\ActivityLog.xml`. Search the log for any extensions reporting an error and uninstall it.

Comment: Here is an answer that explains how to delete an extension without starting VS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55085530/3873799

Answer (score 1):

You need to find file `devenv.exe.config` in `C:\Users\{user_name}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\` and update it. (Or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\`, depending on the location of your `devenv.exe` file.)

For this particular case, you should find rows that setup redirects for `System.Collections.Immutable` and change newVersion from 1.1.36.0 to 1.1.37.0.

The original article is *[How to restore Visual Studio 2015 after the Update 1 (dependency dance)](https://sergeytihon.wordpress.com/2015/12/01/how-to-restore-viual-studio-2015-after-update-1-dependency-dance/)*.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this Connect feedback](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1651928/after-upgrading-from-the-ctp-vs2015-community-edition-to-the-release-visual-studio-explorers-and-designers-package-fails-to-load) I fixed it by closing all opened documents and restarting Visual Studio. I use Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced the same error, "NPM package not installed correctly",
while creating a Node.js project in Visual Studio 2015.

I resolved my issue by performing two steps:

1. Delete all files present in this location:

   ```
   C:\Users\<Your User Name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
   ```

   Restart Visual Studio.
2. Open Visual Studio and go to menu *Tools* → *NuGet Package Manager* → *Package Manager Settings* →

   On the left side: You will see a drop down list: select Node.js, *Tools* → *Npm* → *ClearCache* → *OK

Then again try to create the project. It resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, and projects were not loading correctly or stating that they needed migration. The ActivityLog.xml showed an error with a particular extension. I uninstalled the extension and restarted Visual Studio. That resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the ComponentModelCache folder
2. Delete `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.cache`
3. Restart Visual Studio

Enjoy using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.

After checking ActivityLog.xml and it said that it could not create an instance for the Extension/package name from a specific folder. I traced that path and I didn't find that folder it is looking for.

So I installed the extension again, I looked for the dll, and copied the containing folder contents to the folder Visual Studio is looking for.

So to recap:

1. Check if the folder in the error exists
2. If not, create a new folder with the same name
3. Look for the dll in the error in the Visual Studio folder, if not found, install the extension again
4. If the error resists, search inside the Visual Studio folder in Program Files (x86) for the dll and open the containing folder
5. Copy all the contents
6. Paste inside the new folder you have created with the name mentioned inside the ActivityLog.xml

Answer (score 1):

Firstable, you need to be sure have the last Microsoft .NET Framework version, in my case, I had the 4.6 version and I have downloaded and updated the .NET Framework 4.8.03761 Developer Pack, from the official site:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net48

Once I restarted my PC, to continue fixing that, I solved this problem by clearing Visual Studio Component Model Cache.

Just delete or rename this folder:

%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache
or

%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VPDExpress\11.0\ComponentModelCache
and restart Visual Studio.

Comment: that actually did it for me on VS 2022. Solution by tdracz was not enough. Same solution as most upvoted by user_v

Answer (score 1):

For VS2022 after it got updated to `17.6` I started receveing `The 'whatever-name' package did not load correctly.`

- What worked for me: rebooting my computer
- What didn't work: most upvoted answers for the question

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after installing [Crystal Reports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Reports) for Visual Studio. I solved it by closing all Visual Studio instances and reinstalling Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to mention that I got a similar error in SQL Server Management Studio 2016, where I basically ignored it. Later, I launched Visual Studio (2015), and this error occurred there as well.

I searched and found the answer here recommending that files be deleted from the

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
```

folder. However, in my case, this folder was empty.

Since I remembered that I saw the error in Management Studio first, I checked, and there was a similar folder at

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\13.0\ComponentModelCache
```

This folder was not empty. I closed both Visual Studio and Management Studio, and deleted the files from this folder.

Afterwards, both Management Studio and Visual Studio launched without error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

1. Go to install
2. Modify
3. Go to "Installation location" tab
4. Check "keep download cache after the installation"
5. Modify

Answer (score 0):

My issue was Mysql connector net 6.4.4, Nuget, xamarin, VSPackage, EditorPackage and etc.. package did not load correctly.

My solution is below for vs2015

1. Open AppData location  // all the configurations are updating on it.
2. Backup and Remove the folder in which configuration error is thrown in the visual studio.

forex. If you have Nuget package did not load correctly error - Remove Nuget folder in Local and Roaming directories.

3. And also clear the data on AppData/Microsoft/visual Studio/14.0 for vs2015

that's it and it worked for me!...

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2019: I have done the following things to solve the problem

Backup the following Folder. After Taking backup and Delete This Folder C:\Users\munirul2537\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_add0ca51

Go to the installation panel of visual studio and do the following things

1.Go to install
2.Modify
3.Go to "Installation location" tab
4. Check "keep download cache after the installation"
5. Modify

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2017, 2019. I got this error and able to fix it just by enable the Live Share extension from extensions.

see the VS [community page](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/532561/cascadepackage-package-did-not-load-correctly.html) for detail.

Answer (score 0):

For others that have a similar problem but with live share.

In the visual studio installer there was a warning that live share was not installed correctly and a modification was pending, that would download live share again.

After completion of the modification the error was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for Visual Studio 2019 v16.8.6. It was fixed after repair Visual Studio from Visual Studio Installer.

Answer (score 0):

One more solution that worked for my colleague after trying all the others that did not work (for Visual Studio 2022).

Try this:

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio
2. Go to: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows
3. You should see a number of vX.0-like directories (e.g. v10.0A for Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise). Back-up and remove all those directories except the one matching your Visual Studio (in my case I'd remove everything except v10.0A).
4. Start Visual Studio. The "package did not load correctly" warning will be gone.

Rationale:
If you had older versions of Visual Studio installed previously, they will come with their own NETFX Tools which might not uninstall correctly together with those older instances of Visual Studio. The new Visual Studio will for some reason pick the old Tools and fail using them. Removing the redundant directories fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem. This is how I resolved it:

1. Firstly, I deleted AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_d1adb3fb/ComponentModelCache, and launch Visual Studio 2022, and other window popup.
2. Secondly, I deleted the `ComponentModelCache` again. No error occurred, but the extension is empty.
3. Finally, I upgraded VS 2022 to 17.2.5, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions here worked for me. After a fresh installation of Visual Studio 2022, when opened from Start Menu it opened without any errors. However when launched from command prompt, I got 2 'package did not load correctly' errors (IntelliCodeCppPackage, Global Hub Client Package) and IDE closed automatically. Turns out the root cause in my case was using shortened file path in cmd.

I had it like this:

```
set MS_DEV=C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\Preview
call %MS_DEV%\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat
call %MS_DEV%\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
```

Changing shortened path will full path loaded the packages correctly for me

```
set MS_DEV="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview"
```

Shortened path used to work with Visual Studio 2017, not sure what changed in 2022.

Answer (score 0):

Open Visual Studio with **Run as Administrator**

- The issue is due to lack of permission

Answer (score -1):

After trying lots of options this worked for me (VS 2019):

1. Launch Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019 (Run as Administrator)
2. `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies"` Replace `Community` with your specific distribution.
3. Execute the next line: `gacutil -i Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll`

Answer (score -1):

I read this entire article around 15 times, without success. What worked for me was the following (VS 2022, Release 17.6):

1. Close the VS application
2. Go to "Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\CodeSense\Framework"
3. Run "gacutil -if" to all DLLs there:

   gacutil -if Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeSense.Common.dll

   gacutil -if Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeSense.dll

   gacutil -if Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeSense.Roslyn.dll