# After installed Visual Studio 2010 Professional I am getting an error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have installed VS 2010 Ultimate on Windows 7 Enterprise. It is not working. So I uninstalled that and re-install VS 2010 Professional.

But I am getting an error whenever I open Visual Studio 2010.

Error:

> The 'Visual Studio Tools for Applications v3.0 Shell Integration Package' package did not load correctly.
>
> The Problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more information by running the application together with the log parameter on the command line, and then examining the file
>
> 'C:\users\Name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ActivityLog.xml'.

How to fix this issue? Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling .NET 4.5?

Comment: After examining the log file, what conclusions did you make?

Comment: I don't know how to run log parameter

Comment: VS2012 same issue, nothing from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574089/microsoft-visual-studio-package-did-not-load-correctly worked.

Answer (score 0):

I ran Procmon from Sysinternals on `devenv.exe` with a filter set to capture file system events only, and only not equal 'success' results.

This brought up some results pointing at a directory where `devenv.exe` attempted to load `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Package.dll` from. None of those directories contained that file.

Searched for that file and found it under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Package.dll` That location was not among the directories captured by Procmon.

Copied the file to the first location indicated by the error captured by Procmon and voila, problem solved.