# How Can I Fix the Microsoft Visual Studio Error: Package Did Not Load Correctly

Tags: package, visual-studio-2017

> The 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage' package did not load correctly.
>
> The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension.  You can get more information by exampling the file
>
> 'C:\Users\your-user-name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\your-version-number.*\ActivityLog.xml'.
>
> Continue to show this error message?

I've Tried these support methods:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40418814

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23646013

Though I am getting no luck. Any hep will be appreciated

Comment: Did you try doing a repair on visual studio 2017

Comment: Yes, I also tried restarting my computer I am getting the error "General Diagnostics about running VS session" package did not load correctly

Comment: Each time I am getting a different error.

Comment: Best bet is to uninstall visual studio 2017 with the visual studio uninstaller on github and install it again.  https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller

Comment: Exception details:
System.TypeLoadException: Failure has occurred while loading a type.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsShell5.LoadPackageWithContext(Guid& packageGuid, Int32 reason, Guid& context)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.GetPackage()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft.visual studio package did not load correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574089/microsoft-visual-studio-package-did-not-load-correctly)

Comment: Repair / Update corrected this issue for me.   I think issue (for me) was caused by installing .net 3.5 on Windows 10 …  I had to do certain actions to achieve .net 3.5 install on Windows 10 …  Rad Studio 2007 wanted .net 2 which is included in .net 3.5 apparently.   Habe both Rad Studio 2007 and Visual Studio 2017 running fine on Windows 10 now …

Answer (score 0):

1. Find `ComponentModelCache` folder
2. Delete `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.cache`
3. Restart Visual Studio

Enjoy using Visual Studio.

Comment: This does not work at all. Even deleting the folder itself did not work.

Comment: it didn't work for vs 2022 preview