# Error when previewing MVC views in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

When I preview the code of one of my MVC views in Visual Studio 2015 I get an error popup.

It says

> The 'Microsoft Data Transformation Service Designer' package did not
>   load correctly.
>
> The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more info by
>   viewing ActivityLog.xml

I have tried reinstalling Visual Studio this makes no difference. I have also tried looking at different MVC projects they all display this error.

Anyone have any ideas to fix this error. My projects build fine so I can just ignore it but I would prefer not to if possible.

UPDATE

This is the contents of ActivityLog.xml

```
<type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>CreateInstance failed for package [Microsoft Data Transformation Services Designer][Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]:{   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)}</description>
```

Comment: Did you try reading the ActivityLog.xml file?

Comment: Try like this [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574089/microsoft-visual-studio-package-did-not-loaded#answer-23646013)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps to reset VS, delete the contents from the following folders:

C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio

C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon

Sometimes, you need to go to:

[x64] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE

[x86] C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE

and run `devenv /resetuserdata`.

Expect, that all of your user settings such as Visual Studio layout, linked Microsoft account or start page dissapear.