# dotnet Core: debug does not open browser after upgrade to VS2017

Tags: c#, .net-core, iis-express

My launchSettings.json is (after changing `launchUrl` to `applicationUrl`):

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5050/"
    },
    "Project Development": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5050/"
    }
  }
}
```

Previously both profiles opened `http://localhost:5050/`. Now second profile just starts the server and first shows "The project doesn't know how to run the profile IIS Express" error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37569112/visual-studio-2015-cant-start-iis-express

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2015 can't start IIS Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37569112/visual-studio-2015-cant-start-iis-express)

Comment: that's other case. non-working IIS also not good, but I want working `launchUrl`

Comment: The same error occurred to me in Visual Studio 2019, see how I solved it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63102683/868526