# Upgrading from dnx to vs2017 aspnetcore

Tags: visual-studio-2017

So I just installed VS2017 and loaded my application. It asked to migrate and there were a tonne of issues which I have now fixed. The last remaining issues are the following:

The first one I hope will solve the second. When I try to debug my application it states that:

> the project doesnt know how to run the profile iis express

When I go to the project properties, I can see in the **Debug** tab, there is a IISEXPRESS profile which launches iisexpress. The other two options in the dropdown are **Project** and **Executable**.
I would like to know where the **IISExpress** is pulled from. That obviously needs modifying but it's not like the other two options (which can be changed in the IDE).

Does anyone know how to change it?

**Update**

It looks like the settings are saved in the **launchSettings.json** file.
I added this:

```
"profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
        "commandName": "IISExpress",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
    }
}
```

but still get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurred to me, I use Visual Studio 2019:

> The project doesn't know how to run the profile IIS Express.

**Solution:**
I updated Visual Studio 2019 to the latest version

> Tools -> Get tools and features

Everything worked fine again!

**Installed version:**
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Versão 16.6.5

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a typo in your launchSettings.json

```
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
    "commandName": "IISExpress",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
     }
    },
```

Comment: Yeah saw that, but that was not the issue :(