# Asp.net core boilerplate angular project cannot debug Typescript with VS 2017 in any browser

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core-2.1, aspnetboilerplate

I've installed Visual Studio 2017(v15.9.3).

I downloaded Asp.net core Boilerplate template project with Angular (from https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates). It's server side project working with Asp.net Core 2.1 and client side with Angular, under Asp.net core framework. Server side project working properly and it's run with IIS Express with Chrome.

The issue is, in Angular project I need to debug Typescript in VS with Chrome or whatever browser. But, this Angular project not allowed to run it with any browser. It shows only "IIS Express" and "MyProjectName.AngularUI".

[image]

**(1)** When click on "IIS Express" -> Gives error

> The project doesn't know how to run the profile IIS Express

**(2)** When click on "MyProjectName.AngularUI" -> Gives error

> A project with an output type of class library cannot be started directly

My problem is, how to debug typescript inside this Angular project (comes with Asp.net core Boilerplate framework) inside VS with browser ?

(My contrib. :- In normal Asp.net core Angular projects, Typescript debugging is working correctly). Any solution or clue may highly appreciate.

**NOTE** : Not a possible duplicate of "[How do I debug typescript code in VS 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40944682/how-do-i-debug-typescript-code-in-vs-2017)" Because I can debug normal typescript code in VS. But I cannot debug typescript code which is comes with Asp.net Core Boilerplate framework.

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion @James P . I know that, Angular apps can run using Angular CLI. But then I couldn't debug Typescript inside Visual studio. That's why I'm trying to run inside VS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I debug typescript code in VS 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40944682/how-do-i-debug-typescript-code-in-vs-2017)

Comment: That question is not specific. And also that is not I'm asking. So, it'll not give solution to my question.

Comment: Can you include your launchsettings.json file? That's where the IIS Express and project profiles are defined.

Comment: The same error occurred to me in Visual Studio 2019, see how I solved it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63102683/868526