# Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise cannot start ASPNet Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have the latest VS2017 Enterprise.
I have 'ASP.NET and web development' workload installed.
Also I have .NET Core SDK both versions 32/64 bits.

I create new ASP.NET Core Web Application from template.

When I try to 'Start without debugging' I got an error - "The Project doesn't know how to run the profile IIS Express"

At the same time this project can be run successfully from command line

```
dotnet run
```

I know that similar question exists but all suggestions from it are not helpful in my case
[Visual Studio 2015 can't start IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37569112/visual-studio-2015-cant-start-iis-express)

Comment: Could you provide a screen shot of the `Debug` tab when you right-click the project in Solution Explorer and choose `Properties`?

Comment: @NightOwl888 Here it is http://prntscr.com/ihruf0

Comment: That's weird. I see a lot more fields when I view that tab in an ASP.NET Core project, including settings for configuring the web server, and I am on VS 2017 Community Edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled my VS from scratch and now it works

Comment: I let Visual Studio Installer repair the installation which ended with the demand to restart the system, and it ended up working too. Removing the .vs folder and restarting earlier didn't help. There was never any bad sign during installation.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the vs folder and try to run the project
[image]

The .vs is a hidden folder so you have to enable the Show hidden files

PS: close visual studio before removing the folder

Comment: It didn't help at all