# since last update of my Visual Studio 2013 I get this error How can i solve it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: image of the error]

this error doesnt hamper my performance in developing. Bit its quite annoying and dont know how to solve the problem

Comment: this might be similar to the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574089/microsoft-visual-studio-package-did-not-load-correctly/23159044

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the solution give by Viusal Studio team

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1029189/after-update-4-has-been-installed-such-packages-are-failed-to-load