# MS Visual Studio 2017 error on startup "The 'ExtensionManagerPackage' package did not load correctly"

Tags: visual-studio-2017

After a successful installation of VS 2017, when I start the VS, the following error comes up (see [print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZW5d.png)).

In the error message have a path for ActivityLog.xml file.

ActivityLog.xml include the following informations.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ActivityLog.xsl"?>
<activity>
  <entry>
    <record>1</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:51:20.701</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 version: 15.0.26403.7</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>2</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:51:20.701</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Running in isolation mode.</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>3</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:51:20.966</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>Microsoft Visual Studio Appid Stub</source>
    <description>Application launch on system with DPI X/Y: 96/96</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>4</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:51:38.204</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{00CD9DDA-7350-457C-A240-71BD667FC4DE}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>5</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:51:38.204</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Task Scheduler Package]</description>
    <guid>{00CD9DDA-7350-457C-A240-71BD667FC4DE}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>6</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:51:42.479</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>Package Framework</source>
    <description>Initialized ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider from SetSite.</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>7</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:51:42.962</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Task Scheduler Package]</description>
    <guid>{00CD9DDA-7350-457C-A240-71BD667FC4DE}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>8</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:51:43.586</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{DD7B74B5-C1F9-411A-B22E-5E711592BC6B}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>9</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:51:43.586</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Async Query Service Package]</description>
    <guid>{DD7B74B5-C1F9-411A-B22E-5E711592BC6B}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>10</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:51:43.586</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Async Query Service Package]</description>
    <guid>{DD7B74B5-C1F9-411A-B22E-5E711592BC6B}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>11</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:51:45.755</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{54BEFE64-0558-4D8C-9FD5-AB0B54733B08}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>12</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:51:45.755</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [VSTelemetryPackage]</description>
    <guid>{54BEFE64-0558-4D8C-9FD5-AB0B54733B08}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>13</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:51:45.864</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>Package Framework</source>
    <description>Initialized AsyncServiceProvider.GlobalProvider from SetSite.</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>14</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:51:45.864</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [VSTelemetryPackage]</description>
    <guid>{54BEFE64-0558-4D8C-9FD5-AB0B54733B08}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>15</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:51:50.715</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{FEF989BB-7868-4B73-8864-CC1C3C07A458}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>16</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:51:50.715</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Sign In Package]</description>
    <guid>{FEF989BB-7868-4B73-8864-CC1C3C07A458}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>17</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:51:50.840</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Sign In Package]</description>
    <guid>{FEF989BB-7868-4B73-8864-CC1C3C07A458}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>18</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:51:54.475</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{49D12072-378B-4FFA-A09E-40E0B5D097CC}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>19</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:51:54.475</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Visual Studio Component Model Host Package]</description>
    <guid>{49D12072-378B-4FFA-A09E-40E0B5D097CC}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>20</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:51:57.689</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{5E56B3DB-7964-4588-8D49-D3523AB7BDB9}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>21</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:51:57.689</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Environment Package Window Management]</description>
    <guid>{5E56B3DB-7964-4588-8D49-D3523AB7BDB9}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>22</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:51:57.969</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Environment Package Window Management]</description>
    <guid>{5E56B3DB-7964-4588-8D49-D3523AB7BDB9}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>23</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:51:59.685</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{5E80A5A1-B722-4727-9015-148AAB6310B0}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>24</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:51:59.685</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.UserInformation.UserInformationPackage]</description>
    <guid>{5E80A5A1-B722-4727-9015-148AAB6310B0}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>25</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:52:00.294</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.UserInformation.UserInformationPackage]</description>
    <guid>{5E80A5A1-B722-4727-9015-148AAB6310B0}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>26</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:52:00.543</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{7F679D93-2EB6-47C9-85EB-F6AD16902662}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>27</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:52:00.543</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.ConnectedUserPackage]</description>
    <guid>{7F679D93-2EB6-47C9-85EB-F6AD16902662}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>28</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:52:01.230</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{9C987E78-F0BF-45CA-9BA5-96D3E4B2BAC6}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>29</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:52:01.230</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.AccountManagerService.AccountManagerPackage]</description>
    <guid>{9C987E78-F0BF-45CA-9BA5-96D3E4B2BAC6}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>30</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:52:01.261</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.AccountManagerService.AccountManagerPackage]</description>
    <guid>{9C987E78-F0BF-45CA-9BA5-96D3E4B2BAC6}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>31</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:52:15.629</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{A2863A10-2269-4D3F-9E38-149C15926E1D}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>32</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:52:15.629</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Settings Package]</description>
    <guid>{A2863A10-2269-4D3F-9E38-149C15926E1D}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>33</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:52:15.644</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Settings Package]</description>
    <guid>{A2863A10-2269-4D3F-9E38-149C15926E1D}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>34</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:52:15.707</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.ConnectedUserPackage]</description>
    <guid>{7F679D93-2EB6-47C9-85EB-F6AD16902662}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>35</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:52:17.298</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Visual Studio Component Model Host Package]</description>
    <guid>{49D12072-378B-4FFA-A09E-40E0B5D097CC}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>36</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:52:17.657</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{E7576C05-1874-450C-9E98-CF3A0897A069}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>37</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:52:17.657</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [ExtensionManagerPackage]</description>
    <guid>{E7576C05-1874-450C-9E98-CF3A0897A069}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>38</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:52:18.780</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [ExtensionManagerPackage]Source: &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.Implementation&apos; Description: Could not load type &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.IOleMenuCommand&apos; from assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.IOleMenuCommand&apos; from assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.VSPackage.ExtensionManagerPackage.&lt;InitializeAsync&gt;d__27.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine&amp; stateMachine)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.VSPackage.ExtensionManagerPackage.InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress`1 progress)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass16_0.&lt;&lt;Microsoft-VisualStudio-Shell-Interop-IAsyncLoadablePackageInitialize-Initialize&gt;b__1&gt;d.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.RethrowException(AggregateException e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean ignoreUIThreadCheck)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.GetResult()</description>
    <guid>{E7576C05-1874-450C-9E98-CF3A0897A069}</guid>
    <hr>80131522</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>39</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:52:19.185</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [ExtensionManagerPackage]</description>
    <guid>{E7576C05-1874-450C-9E98-CF3A0897A069}</guid>
    <hr>80131522</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>40</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:52:20.745</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function LoadDTETypeLib</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>41</record>
    <time>2017/04/25 18:52:20.839</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Leaving function LoadDTETypeLib</description>
  </entry>
</activity>
```

I found some solutions suggesting to delete a folder named `ComponentModelCache` but I cannot locate the folder in the suggested path.

What can I do?

Comment: Did try a repair on Visual Studio 2017?  Sounds like something might not have installed properly

Comment: Yes I tried. It successfully completed but the issue remains..

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574089/microsoft-visual-studio-package-did-not-load-correctly

Comment: We struggled almost with the same issue. We rolled back the latest windows updates and it gets to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have install Visual Studio 2005 tools for application you must unistall it. I do this end VS2017 work propertly/.