# Visual Studio 2017 RestorePackageManager did not load correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Whenever I open a solution in Visual Studio 2017 I get the following message.

I tried the proposed solution, [Microsoft.visual studio package did not load correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574089/microsoft-visual-studio-package-did-not-load-correctly) however I'm still getting the error after remov

[Popup that I'm receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw5x9.png)

**Update**

Running a repair fixed the issued.

Comment: did you try running visual studio as administrator?

Comment: I did. I get the same message. This started after I got the latest update for Visual Studio.

Comment: ok. In visual studio command promt (run as administrator) please try the command "Devenv /ResetSettings". It will reset all setting. Please try and let me know

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Running a repair fixed the issued.