# No InprocServer32 registered for package [Visual C++ Resource Editor Package]

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-7-x64, resource-editor

I guess, this happened after recent update to Visual Studio 15.8.0 yesterday. Although I'm not 100% sure that this update caused it. When I try to load resource or open already created `.rc` file this happens:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgaPF.png)

`ActivityLog.xml` says this:

```
<entry>
    <record>533</record>
    <time>2018/08/15 18:01:53.704</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>No InprocServer32 registered for package [Visual C++ Resource Editor Package]</description>
    <guid>{74AAD8B2-3294-49CB-BB5D-E9BAB132BFD5}</guid>
    <hr>8007007f</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\vcpackages\resedit.dll</path>
  </entry>
```

What I tried to do to fix this:

1. All fixes [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574089/microsoft-visual-studio-package-did-not-load-correctly/23159044)
2. Repairing Visual Studio from VS Installer
3. Removing and reinstalling VS from scratch

Nothing works. What could it be and how to fix this? It's not critical, because I still can open `resource.rc`, `resource.h` and manually add resources - it compiles fine. But still rather inconvenient.

Comment: It is a pretty serious mishap, the error code suggests a DLL Hell problem.  Blanket advice is to always avoid a 15.x.0 release, too many changes that haven't been tested well enough.  And waiting for at least the 15.x.3 update so the worst problems have been fixed.  As-is, to get to 3 for everybody else use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem.

Comment: OK, done that. Hope they will fix it soon.

Comment: According to comments at [visualstudio.com](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/281195/resource-view-load-failed.html) there's a dependency problem on Windows 7: resedit.dll depends on an export from UIAutomationCore.dll that isn't provided by the Windows 7 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue with resedit.dll is fixed in MSVS2017 15.8.2.

- Release notes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15.8.2
- Bug report: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/311385/visual-c-resource-editor-package-load-failed.html).

Answer (score 1):

We had the same Problem in our Company. The update works on Windows10 but Windows 7 Systems aren't able to open the resource editor.
Our "dirty" solution was to copy the resedit.dll from an older Visual Studio Version onto the new one.
Hopfully Microsoft brings a bugfixed version soon

Comment: The new Update 15.8.1 didn't bring a new resedit.dll but the workaround still works