# Visual Studio 2019 for Windows 7 - 64bit

Tags: visual-studio-2019

After installing Visual Studio 2019 into my desktop, I'm getting error while opening as
Package Management Initialization Failed.
You can get more information by examining the file.
c:\users<username>\Appdate\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_7adceb78/Activitylog.XML.

Below is the content of the activitylog.xml file.

Failed to process PkgDef file
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\dsltexttemplatingregistry_x86.pkgdef  8007001f VisualStudio 2021/02/21 04:49:45.445
34 ERROR PkgDef loading aborted  8007001f VisualStudio 2021/02/21 04:49:45.445
35 ERROR CPkgDefCacheNonVolatileBase: PkgDef cache creation failed. Going volatile and trying again

I already have dotnet framework 4.7.2 installed. Also I uninstalled and tried to install it again and even after reinstallation the same error is coming.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue, did you get to fix it?

Comment: @snk Did you find any solution?
I experience the same problem.

Comment: This solution worked for me - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51076810/5778921
when I've got the same problem