# Visual Studio 2019 startup "The 'Visual Studio Common IDE Package' package did not load correctly."

Tags: visual-studio

I'm facing this issue when start Visual Studio 2019 new installation:

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

The 'Visual Studio Common IDE Package' package did not load correctly.

The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more information by examining the file 'C:\Users\E0509783_LAR\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_cabeeb93\ActivityLog.xml'.

Restarting Visual Studio could help resolve this issue.

### Continue to show this error message?

### Yes   No

Does anyone idea how to solve?

Thank you in advance.

Luis

Answer (score 1):

The solution with the most upvotes in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574089/how-can-i-fix-the-microsoft-visual-studio-error-package-did-not-load-correctly) post worked for me. I had multiple partially uninstalled instances of Visual Studio 2019 and 2022. As a result, I had multiple 16.0_xxxxxxxx and 17.0_xxxxxxxx folders. I kept the most recent folders and deleted the others, and VS opens with no error message.

Comment: Thank you Michael, I'll follow this path.

Comment: I've tried delete old folders, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had the same problem as yours and I solved it by repairing it from the Visual Studio Installer. You can try

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting this exact same issue for a couple of weeks now on my local dev with vs2022 - it just started.

Tried repairing and re-installing to no avail.
Then yesterday VS stopped loading any projects targeting anything other than .net framework.

Last line in the ActivityLog.XML showed:
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {177F0C4A-1CD3-4DE7-A32C-71DBBB9FA36D} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied.

So I restarted VS2022 in **admin mode** and problems went away. not sure why mine started in the first case as I'm sure I used to start in admin mode from the start.