# Visual Studio problem - can't create a SQL Server database project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have problem with creating a new project for SQL Server database in Visual Studio 2022. Every time I'm trying to create one, I get this error:

[image]

Any suggestion what to do?

I've tried to apply solutions from: [How can I fix the Microsoft Visual Studio error: "package did not load correctly"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574089/how-can-i-fix-the-microsoft-visual-studio-error-package-did-not-load-correctly) None of these works.

Comment: What does that log say?

Comment: Did you try repairing your installation?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't help.

Comment: Hello, because the information you provided is limited. I'll give you a solution first, let me know if it doesn't work.
Tools => Options => Text Editor => C/C++ => Advanced => Disable IntelliSense => True

Comment: Any chance this was on the ARM Visual Studio?  I have this issue as well.