# Error message "No exports were found that match the constraint contract name"

Tags: visual-studio

This morning I faced a problem while opening my Visual Studio solution, and when I tried to run it, it said:

> No exports were found that match the constraint contract name

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Does anyone have an idea as to why this issue occurs?

Answer (score 2198, accepted):

I solved this problem by clearing Visual Studio Component Model Cache.

Just delete or rename this folder:

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache
```

or

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VPDExpress\11.0\ComponentModelCache
```

and restart Visual Studio.

The version of Visual Studio you have is specified by the number e.g.

Visual Studio 2012 is `11.0` (as shown above)

Visual Studio 2013 is `12.0`

Visual Studio 2015 is `14.0`

Visual Studio 2017 is `15.0`

Visual Studio 2019 is `16.0`

For those that don't know: 
`%LocalAppData%\` is the same as `C:\Users\{yourUsername}\AppData\Local`

For those who have multiple versions of Visual Studio installed, e.g. 2012 and 2013, it might help to remove the ComponentModelCache for both versions before restarting Visual Studio, e.g. 11.0 and 12.0.

Comment: Worked for me, too, but for the express version of VS Desktop Developer, I found the cache data in ...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WDExpress

Comment: i cant open my c++ files after **delete all** in that folder, when i restore these files except Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.cache, then reopen my solution then everything back to normal.

Comment: Deleting the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.cache file solved the problem

Comment: I renamed C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache\ and the problem went away.  I listed the full path here in case anyone else needs it.  AppData is hidden, but if you type it in Windows Explorer it can be traversed.

Comment: @alexo, appears for me after installing .net 4.5.1 dev pack on vs 2012

Comment: @alexo In my case, the only reason I could think of why this issue would occur is because there was still a service / server running on your localhost or that atleast some resources were in use, which did not end correctly when shutting down your PC / Laptop.

Comment: @Simon, it worked very well with this: '%AppData%\..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache'
I just removed than boo. worked!

Comment: @RobertFricke I think you should edit the answer and include that (even though it might be obvious, but still)

Comment: Should remove also : ...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VWDExpress\12.0\ComponentModelCache for those working with the express version of VS

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem. I just want to add that my cause of this problem might be that i recently updated my windows. It occurred on the same day. In this update i did update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 for Windows 7 x64-based Systems. even when i restarted my computer this problem was still there. I might be wrong but mt_serg mentioned installing .Net too. During install VS2013 was opened.

Comment: Thanks. I spent the last couple of hours doing everything from reconnecting TFS to downloading new files to running it in admin mode etc. Just renaming the ComponentModelCache folder for VS13 worked.

Comment: God bless your cotton socks.  This has happened to me several times and every time I ran a whole Visual Studio "repair", losing several hours of work.  BTW, this is in VS 2013 - i.e. the bug that causes this is still on the loose!

Comment: It took machine restart in my case after following above steps! Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks, it work. it happen to me several times after windows update. And i keep visiting this thread :)

Comment: Thanks for that! This error happened after I installed an update to fix my IE11 browser console window! The Micro$oft love-hate relationship carries on....

Comment: it works for me also. I have just renamed %AppData%\..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0\ComponentModelCache to another name. For Visual Studio 2016 (15.0)

Comment: Couldn't find the folder for 2013 at the given location but using a search from ..local did the trick ;-)

Comment: This has also fixed my issue of Node.JS interactive window, which used not show up.

Comment: BTW, this started happening to me after removing Node Tools for Visual Studio. So probably a lot of things that muck with plugins may cause it. This solution worked.

Comment: I got this issue after installing SSMS 2016, which runs on VS 2015 shell. I am using VS 2013 on this machine. Though it may have been caused by shutting down my machine and not waiting for VS to completely close or an update.

Comment: This extension does this automatically for you with one click (including restarting VS): Clear MEF Component Cache https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/22b94661-70c7-4a93-9ca3-8b6dd45f47cd

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much. I got this issue after installing Team Foundation Server.

Comment: Thanks... Was looking for same,,,,i my case Power Productivity tool was main problem

Comment: In my case VS2019 the folder was named 16.0_8ab085c4

Answer (score 154):

No need to rename or delete the whole folder:

```
(%AppData%\..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache)
```

Just rename or delete the **`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.cache`** file inside the above location.

Comment: if delete all in this folder, c++ file maybe unable to open.

Comment: This was life saving. Thanks Ananta.

Answer (score 73):

Visual Studio Express 2012 has different paths.

**Visual Studio Express**

- ...\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WDExpress\11.0\ComponentModelCache

**With Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web**

- ...\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VWDExpress\11.0\ComponentModelCache

I did not have to re-install Visual Studio Express

Answer (score 37):

This will really work like a champ:

Solution: Try to delete ComponentModelCache folder from the below location.

```
[C:]\Users\[your user name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\[Visual Studio version number]
```

And after successful delete, recreate the folder with the same name, "ComponentModelCache".

Comment: This is the same as [the highest-voted and accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17604007/150605), as well as a few other contemporary answers.

Answer (score 28):

Deleting the Component Model Cache did not work for me (well, the relative directory given above did not exist in my machine). Instead, I installed an extension to [Visual Studio 2012 Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express). Menu *Tools* → *Extensions and Updates...* → *Online* → *Choose any* and then download. This apparently invalidates the cache causing Visual Studio to rebuild it.

Here's my [source](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/794111/no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name).

Comment: Visual Studio --EXPRESS-- has a different location. Check the other answers in this thread.

Comment: In my case it happened after install xamarin extention in VS2015 comunity. after remove all goes well. I remove it in the same place that in this answer.
Tools > Extensions and Updates

Answer (score 28):

This issue can be resolved by deleting or clearing all the folders and files from `%AppData%\..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache`

This actually clears the Visual Studio component model cache.

On Windows 7 machines, the path is different. When you type `%appdata%` in *Run* dialog, it opens the folder `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming`.

Click the 'up' button to navigate to the parent folder and select the folder 'Local'.

Final path: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache`

Answer (score 21):

For Visual Studio 2013 you need to remove that folder from this path:

```
%AppData%\..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0
```

Comment: I experienced this after my battery ran out installing a rather large xamarin update for vs2013. Went into this folder, renamed the ComponenetModelCache and upon restart it recreated the folder and it was fixed.  Ty

Comment: Also worked for another error for me: `'visual c++ package' failed to load`

Answer (score 20):

for **Visual Studio 2012** and later versions, the solution must be deleting the content of the folder **`ComponentModelCache`**:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WDExpress\11.0\ComponentModelCache
```

**Visual Studio 2013**

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache
```

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem upon launching Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, and the solutions here didn't work for me. I tried deleting the mentioned folders and starting Visual Studio again, but it didn't work.

However I had other problems too, like *[Microsoft.visual studio package did not load correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574089/microsoft-visual-studio-package-did-not-loaded/23159044#23159044)* and also *[Page '312e8a59-2712-48a1-863e-0ef4e67961fc' not found VS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088826/page-312e8a59-2712-48a1-863e-0ef4e67961fc-not-found-vs-2012)*. The latter refers to a message in the Team Explorer window saying "Page 'somenumber' cannot be found".

So I run `devenv /setup` on the Visual Studio command prompt with administrative rights. It did the job, and everything is fine now.

Comment: I was deleting the folder specified (Win 8.1, VS 2013 Prem) and it kept coming back every time I closed and re-opened VS.

This unfortunately did not work either.

Comment: After trying several solutions did was the trick that solved my problems.

Because the VS Command Prompt for VS2013 isn't easy to find here is the path to it:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\Shortcuts

Comment: devenv /setup fixed a crashing problem with VS 2015 Pro for me. The ComponentModelCache was not fixing it.

Comment: Wow - didn't expect this to work, but it did!  VS 2017 Community edition.

Answer (score 13):

Remove ***ComponentModelCache*** folder content.

```
 %AppData%..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache
```

Answer (score 11):

Clearing the folders didn't work for me. So I went to 'Programs and Features' and used the change button to startup the Visual Studio 2013 setup.

In the setup I choose the repair function and that fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio Express 2013 of Windows 8.1.

Unfortunatly there was no "ComponentModelCache" folder in 
%AppData%..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache.

I found the "ComponentModelCache" folder in 
..\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WDExpress\12.0

and solved this problem by removing this folder from there.

Answer (score 8):

If you have VS 2013, you have to go to: **%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0**
then rename the ComponentModelCache folder.

Comment: +1 for %LOCALAPPDATA% , I was using %AppData% and didnt find any folder like ComponentModelCache. But using %LOCALAPPDATA% I can get it.

Answer (score 7):

I experienced a similar problem after some updates released from Microsoft (part of them where about .NET framework 4.5).

On the Internet I got the following link to the Microsoft knowledge base article:

*[Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 (KB2781514)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2781514)*

It worked for me.

Comment: +1 - Great find! This solved the problem for me. It is the legitimate solution instead of hackishly deleting the cache file which could have implications in the future.

Comment: Except that this problem still exists in VS2015, so this is unlikely to be the 'legitimate solution'.

Answer (score 6):

This happened to me with Visual Studio 2013 Web, after Windows installed several updates. Unfortunately none of the suggestions in this thread helped.

I had to re-run the installer and select the "Repair" option. After that (and a reboot) it was working once again.

In some cases you may have to repair more than one version of Visual Studio. One example is when a Script Task control in VS 2013 opens VS 2012 when you click Edit Script.

Answer (score 4):

Renaming the ComponentModelCache folder worked for me in Visual Studio 2015, but with a slightly different path:

```
%AppData%\..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
```

Answer (score 3):

I have Windows 7 x64 with a second partition on which Windows 8 (preview installed). While working with Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone, I come up with the same problem. But the ComponentModelCache is found here:

C:\Users\Jayaram\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VPDExpress\11.0

I am unable to delete or rename as I get the "access is denied" message when I try to use command prompt:

Administrator: VS2012 X64 CrossToolsCommandPrompt

Answer (score 3):

I am using Visual Studio 2012. After installing the Visual Studio 2013 web express, when I want to run or open any project in Visual Studio 2012 it shows me the following error:

> "**no exports were found that match the constraint contract name"**.

I also tried the above solution for clearing the **ComponentModelCache**,
but I did not find the folder. I solves my problem just by: **Repair Visual Studio 2012**

For the Express versions of the software, the folder you need is in a slightly different place(s): For Express 2012 for Web it is `C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VWDExpress` - not in the Visual Studio folder.

Comment: it happened for me in 2013 with that being the only visual studio installed on my machine - did repair, as you mentioned via the "uninstall a program" panel and it was fixed.

Comment: I didnt find the folder too initially by using %AppData% but by using %LOCALAPPDATA% I could naviagte and find the folder

Comment: bingo,,,,this one is more accurate answer for me

Answer (score 3):

This issue is because of a MEF cache corruption. 
Installing the feedback extension (or installing any extension) will invalidate the cache causing VS to rebuild it.

[click for source.](http://www.hjerpbakk.com/blog/2014/7/25/no-content-in-solution-explorer-using-visual-studio-2013)

Answer (score 3):

i experienced this problem in Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for windows phone while trying to open file.

Then i browsed to

> C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VPDExpress\11.0\ComponentModelCache

And Inside ComponentModelCache i deleted Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.cache CACHE file. Finaly i restarted visual studio and reopened my project.

Then my problem was solved, i was able to open file.

Note: My OS is windows 8. And i installed SDK 8 for developing windows phone app

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I got an error with the same error message - two years later.
It's a different problem this time though, related to .NET Core dnx things.

I couldn't find an answer on Stack Overflow, but there's a GitHub issue that contains a workaround: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1455

Below is the most important part of the workaround:

> - Delete the entire `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>     14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\DNX` directory. (As far as I understand, it belongs to the old version of ASP.NET Core
>     RC1, which for some reason is still shipped even with Visual Studio 2015 Update-3).
> - Delete the `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\devenv.exe.config` file.
> - Run the Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2015 as Administrator, and execute the `devenv /setup` command. The new devenv.exe.config file is generated. This time there are many assemblies that refer to the
>     `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\DotNet` directory.
> - Run the Visual Studio 2015 and check that it shows the Microsoft .NET Core Tools (Preview 2) 14.1.20624.0 in the Help => About Microsoft Visual Studio menu.

Thanks to *olegburov*'s post on GitHub for figuring this out.

Answer (score 1):

I had to uninstall some external components like Postsharp and Apex and then it worked. I also tried the chosen solution but it gave me more errors.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the folders haven't worked for me i have go control panel and repaired

```
Visual Studio Installer Projects extensions for VS 2013.
```

And it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Removing `ComponentModelCache` did not work for me.  **Reinstalling VS 2019 did** thanks to a recommendation on [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/784506/package-manager-multiple-errors-displayed-on-tools.html) Microsoft support thread.

Details

- This seems to be a known bug with a fix incoming from MS (as of 1/7/2020)
- Experienced after upgrading from VS2019 Pro 16.2 (i think it was?) to 16.4.2 using Visual Studio Installer
- Error displayed when trying to launch both nuget console and nuget package manager

Comment: Agree with w00ngy. But **it wasn't necessary**, for me, **to reinstall VS 2019**. Just applying the updates did the job (in VS 2019, see **Help** menu, item **Check for Updates**). Thanks for the hint though!

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after reinstalling [IntelliJ IDEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) and [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) for C# in Visual Studio 2013.

First, I got an error problem with extensions, and after this I got this error:

> "No exports were found that match the constraint contract name”

I simply removed folder ComponentModelCache and resolved this error.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:
Following all above lifesaving tips, I had a slightly different experience; mine is VS 2017 Community Edition, installed once, and I notice that have all these 3 folders:

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0 ==> Empty
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\7f0c75b0 ==> has only the CoreCon folder
```

This is the one that has the ComponentModelCache:

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_7f0c75b0
```

Deleting only the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.cache had no effect.

So, I deleted all 4 files there: .cache, .err, .external and catalogs.
On restarting VS, problem gone and appeared a 5th file:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.scan
```