# Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate Crashes when debugging Asp.Net MVC4 Application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

When i running the Asp.Net MVC 4 application with VS2012 Ultimate means it works fine. But if i try to debug the application, VS is completely crashing and try to restart the application.

I installed all updates for VS2012 (Up To VS2012 Update 4)

My application is not a huge one. For Example, please create Asp.Net MVC 4 empty project and try to debug. You will see the issue.

My System Configuration:

OS: Windows 8 Single Language

Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3337U CPU @ 1.80GHz

RAM: 4.00GB

System Type: 64bit

Pen and Touch Support: Full windows touch support with Touch Points.

Manufacturer of System : Acer

Model: Aspire|V5

Any one please provide your suggestion to overcome this problem.

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17762118/736079

Comment: Please check out the above post and update your question with the relevant Eventlog messages and/or the contents of your visual studio ActivityLog.xml.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using windows authentication, then you need to point to Local IIS server intead of Development server. And then need to enable the Windows Authentication in IIS.

Comment: This is more of a comment not an answer