# operation could not be completed error while opening VS2012

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012

I have recently updated windows but the visual studio related updates failed to install.
after that i have been constantly getting the above mentioned error. and just unable to run my VS2012.[image: Screen shot of the error]

Comment: Have you tried repairing Visual Studio and tried re-applying the updates?

Comment: yes i have tried repairing Visual Studio and re-applying updates... nothing worked. one thing to notice though that i have two versions of Visual Studio viz. 2010 and 2012 both are not working after the update. the updates always get failed while applying. i guess the dot net framework has been corrupted while updating.

Comment: System restore is also not working ... i have even tried uninstalling and re-installing dot net 4.5 which i couldn't. :(

Comment: Sounds like an issue for SuperUser, your windows installation seems corrupted. You can try running Visual Studio in safe mode an/or with logging enabled. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17762118/736079

Comment: Try to uninstall Vs2012, then vs2010. Then instal vs2010 and update it. Then install vs2012 and update it.