# Visual Studio stops working on build

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, installshield

When I try to build my solution (consisting of a WPF project (C#), a test project and the installShield install project) I get the error that "Visual studio has stopped working" and after a while "Visual studio is restarting".

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Profesional and InstallShield LE.

It used to work just fine and I have no idea why it stopped working, I do not get any sort of indications where the problem might lie. I've tried "clean" solution and "rebuild" but it does not solve the problem. Anyone who have stumbled upon this error and remember how they solved it?

I've tried different configuration combinations from the Configuration manager but I do not find any solution to this irritating behavior.

The question is vague but it is only because I do not get any error messages...

**UPDATE**
So I removed the Install project and now I can build the solution, I wonder if this means that there is something wrong with some build order or something like that. The strange thing is that there does not seem to be anything wrong with the install project in it self. And there is no dependencies between the two.

Comment: Check the Event Viewer for any errors related yo this, try running visual studio with logging enabled. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/02/24/troubleshooting-with-the-activity-log.aspx

Comment: I'm trying to do the loggin, but it does not create any log file. Does not create if I choose to specify the path or doing the default run?

Comment: Are you looking in the right place?  I see that the blog post points to VS2010, and the location changes with the version of VS. For VS2012: `%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ActivityLog.XML`.

For VS2013: `%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog.XML`.

Comment: Ok now I found it, no idea why it was not there before... I do not see anything about something similar to "error" / "exception" or something like that, any idea what I'm looking for?

Comment: Basic debugging steps for VS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761855/visual-studio-2012-crashes-when-trying-to-update-repair-deinstall/17762118#17762118