# Microsoft visual studio 2013 has stopped working - windows 8.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I get error in visual studio 2013 when that reach to a special line and Suddenly Visual studio crashes and show this message
[image: Error Message]

Special line is :

```
 Plans_Customers plan = model.Plans_Customers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ConfirmCode == code);
```

I researched and found links like these [Visual Studio 2012 has stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076487/visual-studio-2012-has-stopped-working-when-solution-is-opened) and
[no exports were found...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name) and [Visual Studio 2013 Professional RC has Stopped Working](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1c92fece-1a2d-40e3-843e-2760a70ab040/visual-studio-2013-professional-rc-has-stopped-working?forum=visualstudiogeneral),.. but not help me
My Visual studio is correct for other project and working correctly in other lines of this project, just has error in this line!!! why? Can anyone help me?

**Update :** I found my answer :  got to Tools=> Option =>Debugging > General On *Use Managed Compatibility Mode*

Comment: You can [debug Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698388/how-to-troubleshoot-and-debug-visual-studio-design-mode-errors) itself to see what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As I've experienced with "0x0000 referenced at memory 0x0000. The memory could not be read" 
I've only had issues sometimes, while reading certain memory slots, but gradually my hard disk broke.

I'd try migrating the project, running it on other PC if you're available. Just to make sure it's not about the PC's memory itself.

Comment: I test on another pc but i have same error in same line