# Visual Studio 2013 crashing when saving Windows Forms solution

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2013

I have been working on a particular solution for a few months now without any problems.  The last thing of significance that I remember doing was refactoring the name of a custom control inheriting from RichTextBox.  I don't know if that is related to the problem but it seemed to be when the problems started occurring.  For some reason now when I show the main form in design view and save any changes I get the message "Visual Studio has stopped working blah blah" and it restarts.

I seem to be able to load and make changes to other solutions ok.

So far I've tried:

- Deleting .sln and v12.sln files
- Have tried uninstalling NuGet. (I    don't have any extensions other than        NuGet and Visual Studio    Extensions for Windows Library for JavaScript)
- I don't have resharper
- I have tried to start in /SafeMode but I keep getting the error    "'Visual Studio Component Model Host Package' package did not load    correctly".  I can't seem to load any solutions in SafeMode.
- Repaired    VS2013 installation twice
- Restarted my computer many times
- Tried    writing a log file using /log switch but can't really understand how    to interpret it.

Any pointers would be very welcome.

Comment: "Visual Studio has stopped working blah blah" isn't at all helpful.  Please update your post with specific error messages.  Copying/pasting error text from `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Version\ActivityLog.xml` is probably a good place to start.  Also look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076487) and try this: `Tools > Import & Export Settings  >  Reset all settings`

Comment: I'm sorry but that's basically all the message says.

Comment: I have tried Reset all settings yes

Comment: Is there anything specific I should be looking for in the log file?  There are lots of <type>information</type> and <type>warning</type> but no actual errors

Comment: 1) There should be *something* useful *somewhere* in the logs.  But I can't tell you a priori what to look for :(  2) Do look at the link I posted, as well as the link(s) it references.  3) Delete the .suo file, and everything under the bin/* and obj/* subfolders.  4) If it's just one solution (and everything else works OK) ... maybe your only recourse is to create a new solution (and copy in the old source).

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at those links.  It did cross my mind that I might have to cut and paste code.  Hopefully it won't get to that.