# Error in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 :No exports were found that match the constraint

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When I opened my Project in VS2012 , I got an error

> No exports were found that match the constraint:
>
> ContractName
>     Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.IContentTypeRegistryService
>                            RequiredTypeIdentity
>  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.IContentTypeRegistryService
>
> Please correct before proceeding. (You might rename the current web.config and add a new one).

Why did this happen, can someone please suggest a solution?

Comment: Here is the solution to this problem,

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name

Comment: exact duplicate of [Error message "No exports were found that match the constraint contract name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name)

Answer (score 159):

I solved this problem by clearing the Visual Studio Component Model Cache.
Just delete or rename this folder:

> %AppData%\..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache

Or, for Visual Studio 2013:

> %AppData%\..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache

Comment: You can use %LocalAppData% instead of %AppData%\..\Local

Answer (score 14):

I have fix this with update :

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36020#

I'm on windows 8.1 and Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Just had this problem, tried your method, it worked,
Thanks a lot :) +1

Answer (score 13):

I encountered similar issue and found this solution like magic. The steps go here:

- Delete ComponentModelCache folder from below location:

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0

- Make it sure to replace  with your real user name on your pc.
- Once deleted, recreate the folder with same name "ComponentModelCache".
- In case, it gives any permissions issue, deleting the remaining files/folders one by one can work well.

The error is no more there when you try to create a project in visual studio.