# .cs files can't be opened anymore in VS 2013 Professional Update 4

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-2013

I'm facing a problem where I can't open .cs files in Visual Studio 2013 after one day.

It started on Monday: I opened an existing solution and tried to open the Program.cs file but instead was met with the following error message (rough translation):

> No exports were found that meet the constraint:
>
> ContractName
>
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.IContentTypeRegistryService
>
> RequiredTypeIdentity
>
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.IContentTypeRegistryService

I tried opening .cs files in different solutions and always got the same message. The only exception being: Any Visual Studio instance that was opened before the Visual Studio instance in which the exception first occured was/is not affected by this.

I managed to get it working by choosing to repair the Visual Studio installation and rebooting but that only worked until the next day.

I tried searching for that message but got nothing so far.

Comment: Already solved in here, the same should work since 2012 and 2013 are very similiar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217506/error-in-microsoft-visual-studio-2012-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-cons

Comment: @JonathanCamilleri this is rather embarrassing...I even edited an answer on that question 12 days ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete or rename this folder:

> C:\users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache\

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and seems the file was open - but I could see what pane or anything.  So I had to right click on a file and close all documents - then I could open the file again.