# VS2012/2013 fails to display solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have this problem with both VS2012 and 2013. When I load an existing or create a new solution I get a ProviderPackage error - An exception was thrown during package instantiation and was caught in the package manager. After I close the error dialog, the solution explorer window is empty, although there are solution files open in the editor.

The ActivityLog.xml file shows different modules loading when the error occurs, depending on the project type. Is there a way that I can determine the common thread between 2012 and 2013 that is causing this error.

There is probably a corrupted dll which I have to replace. I am dead in the water until I figure this out.

Help.

Comment: Moved this question to MS support.

Comment: I tried this and worked for me.
[clear cache model][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name

Answer (score 36):

Clearing the Visual Studio Component Model Cache worked for me (details: [Error message "No exports were found that match the constraint contract name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name))

Comment: VS 2012 -    %AppData%\..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache 
     
VS 2013 -   %AppData%\..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache

Answer (score 7):

None of the previous suggestions worked for me, but this one did:
http://www.hjerpbakk.com/blog/2014/7/25/no-content-in-solution-explorer-using-visual-studio-2013

> This issue is because of a MEF cache corruption. Installing [or uninstalling any extension] will invalidate the cache causing VS to rebuild it.

Comment: This one works!! I still cannot believe installing an arbitrary extension is the fix....

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the empty solution explorer with Visual Studio 2013, and fixed it [with a repair install](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983433%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**:  This worked for me.
I had the same problem in Visual Studio 2015 with the *Solution Explorer* always showing empty, even after deleting the *ComponentModelCache* folder.  Looking at the *Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.err* file, one of the errors was:

"*----- Catalog construction errors -----
Error #1
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscoveryException: Failure while scanning type ......*"

Doing a Google search on *Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.PartDiscoveryException* lead me to a Nuget package for *Visual Studio MEF*.    Since I read so many posts of people have this same problem, I figured the problem was with Visual Studio and not necessarily any particular extension.  So I installed this *Visual Studio MEF* Nuget package, restarted Visual Studio, and now the Solution Explorer is populated every time.

Nuget:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition/

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the .suo file worked for me.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

Close VS, delete suo file of your project (is hidden), open your project again. 
I had this problem with two projects, this fixed it in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Also, creating a new project (in my case a Console Application) also worked! That was probably the easiest fix i've found thus far and you don't have to delete anything! Nice...

Answer (score 0):

Go To Window menu in visual studio and click reset window layout...it will work