# Visual Studio 2013 error: no exports were found

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I dont know what to make of this error

[image]

It comes anytime I try to click on any file in my project or solution. This has happened all of a sudden. I was only trying to register WCF on my system using [this link](http://sourcefield.blogspot.in/2008/11/register-wcf-service-on-iis-by.html)
I don't think they are related but I cant think of any reason why it would stop working all of a sudden.

Comment: try closing vs, then doing "devenv /setup" and starting vs again

Comment: where do I do devenv /setup ?

Comment: Looks like it was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name

Comment: thanks dan. I wonder how I didnt get that solution when I searched

Comment: you'd do the devenv /setup on a standard developer command prompt.  you probably didn't get the suggestion because all of the useful text was in your screenshot.  if you have a windows error dialog visible and do ctrl+c, it *generally* will copy the text of the message to the clipboard.