# Visual Studio Solution Explorer not showing files and folders

Tags: visual-studio-2013, solution-explorer

Suddenly my solution tab stopped working on my Visual Studio 2013. Even it is existing project or brand new project it does not show files and folders in Solution Explorer. (File is attached)

I tried to reset settings, restarted PC but did not work.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075(v=vs.100).aspx

I did not installed any new extensions recently I was working what ever I had for a while.

Is there anything else I can do?

[image]

Update;

I am also getting this weird message when I click options Icon:

[image]

Comment: Check this out: http://www.hjerpbakk.com/blog/2014/7/25/no-content-in-solution-explorer-using-visual-studio-2013. To quote... "This issue is because of a MEF cache corruption. Installing the feedback extension (or installing any extension) will invalidate the cache causing VS to rebuild it."

Comment: Thanks for redirection, works now! I think you can post your comment as an answer which is totally working now :)

Comment: Glad I could help! I'll post the comment as answer.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540237/visual-studio-2015-missing-content-in-solution-explorer-branches

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check this out: http://www.hjerpbakk.com/blog/2014/7/25/no-content-in-solution-explorer-using-visual-studio-2013

To quote... "This issue is because of a MEF cache corruption. Installing the feedback extension (or installing any extension) will invalidate the cache causing VS to rebuild it."

Link to bug report: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/794111/no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name

Comment: Personally, rather than install an unwanted extension, I just updated an extension on the update list (I generally have at least one item that needs updating!). That work as well.

Comment: You might consider installing this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ClearMEFComponentCache

Answer (score 19):

Rebuilding didn't work for me, and I wasn't keen on installing another extension.

Got it to work in the following three steps:

1. Click "Show All Files" in solution explorer (in bar above search bar)
   [image: Image showing location of Show All Files]
2. Right click folder that was previously missing, select "Include In Project"
3. Click (unselect) "Show All Files" in solution explorer.

Answer (score 15):

Just to get the answer here on the same page as the question: users should install (or uninstall) an extension to Visual Studio as this will force a rebuild of the MEF cache. The linked article suggested installing the *Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Feedback Tool* extension, which I did do and it worked, but any extension installed through the **Tools, Extensions and Updates** menu would probably do the job.

I think the cause of this might have been related to an overzealous anti-virus program, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: When I followed this advice, I got a popup: "No exports were found that match the constraint contract name" and could not proceed. Searching on that message lead me to [the recommendation to delete the VS Component Model folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name), which resolved all problems for me.

Answer (score 11):

it worked to click "show all files" in the Solution explorer!

Answer (score 2):

As this issue is because of a MEF cache corruption. Just delete your .vs folder and re-open your solution.

Comment: Best and quickest way if you don't care about vs config for the local project in that directory. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For future Googlers / related issue in 2023, "Explorer" was not showing up for me in the sidebar at all. No way to view files and folders.

I had to delete the `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage` folder to get it to show up.

Answer (score 1):

Even, it will work if you clear your local app data for visual studio.
%temp% AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio. 
%temp% AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio.
Delete the files and restart your visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy and paste the folders and files at the project location for integrating the project module and build the project even though namespace has correct. This are the way to resolve
2. The file/folder is not visible proper so Right-click 
   [image] improper visible file/folder and click the Include in Project
3. Build the project -> If any error occur then it like namespace may be error because copy from one project to another project or else same project with different location so that check it
4. If the error like Build action 'Page' is not supported by the specific combination of the project's targets.
5. Go and resolve by further steps [image]

Comment: Needs more work/steps.  Of course if you copy a XAML page from one project to another, you're going to have namespace issues.  I tried pulling in another page into a project where it was not reading files below the first folder level.  If I added it to the project root, it added fine.  If I added it to a folder, it could not see the file.  So I doubt wherever you put files that the Solution Explorer is going to miraculously pick them up - you have to tell it to load them by doing "Add Existing Item" in VS and point at them.

Comment: As FYI for any that are curious, I solved my issue by ensuring that I could open folders in Solution Explorer and see subitems from another project in a separate VS, so I knew I didn't have a VS-wide problem. So I just re-created a new project and moved my files into them, created new references again, etc. But then it started again after building my project. So I had files in multiple namespaces.  Once I got them all in one namespace and restarted VS, everything worked again.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Right-click on the project
2. Rebuild

Answer (score 0):

with VS 2022 most of you must be trying to create a .NET 6 framework solutions. But you need to install the .NET 6 sdk separately for your projects to be listed under solution.

Installing .NET 6 SDK, resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post looking for a solution about some methods not being found on Solution Explorer. Just in case, VS 2022 has options to search for methods within File Contents, see image below, activating this option my issue was solved:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Open the Solution Explorer and click on Show All Files Button, it will show the files which were there in your project and you were unable to see them. Then if you want to include them in your project, select the folder and right-click on it and select Include in the project.

Comment: Sorry, @Nupur, it would be nice if that was working in the case of the original poster's circumstance, but it's clearly not.