# Visual Studio not showing all Projects in solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, solution-explorer

I'm not sure why, but Visual Studio is not showing all the projects in my solution.  I need them to show so I can set as default project under solution explorer.  I'm not seeing a fix for this issue in a general internet search.  The closest I see is [VS not showing files folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912433/visual-studio-solution-explorer-not-showing-files-and-folders), but this is different than my issue.  Hopefully there is an easy way to fix it, without adding things again piecemeal.  My co-workers can see their complete set of projects in solution explorer so it must be a corruption in my workspace.

Comment: close the solution and open it again. Or try "Add existing project"...

Comment: Closing and opening the solution didn't fix it.  I shouldn't have to add existing project, since it's supposed to be in there already.  My old co-worker used to have a file that I could remove, but I don't have notes on it now.  When I entered Visual Studio again, the file would be re-created by Visual Studio.

Comment: This is a little late to the party but I ran into a _similar problem with VS2019_ and thought I'd leave a note that the issue was in a path created by `git clone`. The source repo had "A name with banks" and the default directory name on the machine was thus "A%20name%20with%20blanks". Apparently VS2019 doesn't like URL escape chars in the folder path. After removing them everything worked fine.

Comment: This happened to me after pulling a change that added a new project to the solution. The project didn't appear at first. Restarting Visual Studio (2017) made the project appear.

Comment: There appears to be some issue related to the use of .slnf files and this issue... Haven't pinned down the exact steps yet though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to copy out changed files in my workspace, fix my permissions/ownership on my directory (it was no owner instead of me), re-do the mapped drive the workspace was on, re-do the shortcut to the Visual Studio project (even though it was supposed to theoretically be the same place I mapped), re-pull the project down, and copy my changes in again.  At this point Visual Studio had the missing solutions in it again so I could set startup project and run the debugger.  I'm not sure how the ownership/permissions got messed up.  I think at one point the other office had a server go down, and maybe my permissions/ownership got mixed up then. I'm not sure why VS wasn't showing the missing projects, but it's fixed after doing the above.

Answer (score 17):

Open your ".sln" project file using Notepad. 
In this file you can observe listed projects like below

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "test.myProject.Data", "test.myProject.Data\test.myProject.csproj", "{6D7F7B84-F3BD-4A19-A069-D144C345B887}"
EndProject
```

Please add if there any missing projects. If you have old back up or co-workers file, Just copy and paste missing projects to this file.
In my case it works !!

Comment: Or click "Compare with unmodified" on your git/tfs thing. And then revert/copypaste changes.

Answer (score 15):

close vs , delete .vs folder then open vs again. it works for me.

Comment: where is the .vs folder?

Comment: Right click to you solution in Solution Explorer, then Click Open Folder in File Explorer. You will see .vs folder there!

Answer (score 7):

I found that re-adding the existing project to the solution worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

If the other solutions didn't work for you, then try this.

You can add the missing project to the solution file using the `dotnet` command. To do so, go to the root folder of your project and run the following command from the terminal:

```
dotnet sln add ProjectLibrary/ProjectLibrary.csproj
```

The `ProjectLibrary/ProjectLibrary.csproj` is the path to your missing project.

You can open the `.sln` file to confirm if the prject has been added. You should see something like:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "ProjectLibrary", "ProjectLibrary\ProjectLibrary.csproj", "{F042B1DB-F887-44CC-941A-76569A86AF75}"
EndProject
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue where my colleague saw 1 more project on his computer.

I deleted my .sln file and got the exact same version as he. Problem was still the same.

Solution was: I had an unloaded project. Apparently this is safed in a local user setting file (probably the .suo file). I looked for the unloaded project and loaded it again.

Comment: Where is the local user settings file/the .suo file you  mentioned about ??

Comment: @Sanjok should be next to the solution file - if you did some changes for your own local copy.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close the VStudio entire project, go to the main project folder and click on the .sln file to load the entire project agian.
2. go to solution explorer see which are having (unload), right click and load project with dependencies
3. sometimes check if the project startup has changed, if changed just right click on the related project and set as project startup

Answer (score 0):

[This .sln file structure breakdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/solution-dot-sln-file?view=vs-2022)   offers a great insight on how projects are able to be found and populated into the project hierarchy. My .sln file had lost all its project persistence blocks and thus I had 0 projects under my solution. I copied the blocks from a a previous git commit and this fixed it. I still don't know why the blocks disappeared or the whole .sln file changed

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Right click the Solution name in the Solution Explorer. Click **Add > Existing Project...** The Add Existing Project window will appear. Select the project file. It will be included in the solution.

[click to see how to add the project file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYHet.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think I found (part of) the problem and the solution, at least as far as I experienced it!

Most of the projects disappeared. Nothing of the above suggestions helped. I edited the solution file with Notepad and deleted manually all references to one of the projects that was not visible. I then added the project back from Visual Studio. (It didn't have to be closed, as it picked up the file change in the background and reloaded the solution.) My project became visible again. When I compared the solution file with what was before, I found out that the re-added project was missing from a section at the very bottom curiously titled:

GlobalSection(NestedProjects) = preSolution
...

Then I deleted the entire "nested projects" section. Voila! All the hidden projects are visible again.

I could not find what they were nested in before. None of the visible projects contained the "nested ones" in any way. They are surely in the dependencies of some of the visible projects, but you cannot work with them in the dependencies  section.

Again, the solution was to edit the solution file with Notepad and delete the section about nested projects at the bottom.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. After opening the Visual Studio in Administrator mode it started to work.

Search for VS->Right click-> "Run as administrator"

Comment: Can be a security risk