# visual studio 2015 can not see all projects in solution explorer

Tags: git, visual-studio

In my solution explorer there are several projects, but when I open project it shows just one of them. It has begun act like that after merging our branches in git. And I would like to say that me and my co-worker use different versions of visual studio. I use 2015, but my co-worker use 2017. I looked at this solution [Visual Studio not showing all Projects in solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772243/visual-studio-not-showing-all-projects-in-solution). After changing .sln file, now it shows the other projects, but the problem is that now it does not show some controllers under Controllers folder. I see .cs files inside Controllers folder

[image]

but I can not see those .cs files in visual studio under Controllers, and only can see those files after clicking show all files icon in vs.

[image]

I would like to know why is it like that and how to prevent this case to happen? After every merge do I have to do these operations? What did we do wrong while merging? And is it okay to use different versions of visual studio for the same project because I see this cause some problems when try to merge in git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your co-worker probably didn't pushed .csproj after work (usually it could be because of it not vissible what that file updated until you close VS, or click Save All). Same for adding new projects to solution, probably your co-worker didn't save all, and push .sln.

You have to `Include In Project` that files, then Save All (to save .csproj file, not only .cs), and then commit/push .csproj file to git.

[image: Include]