# When i add a new project in Visual Studio it does not get added to the solution file

Tags: visual-studio-2019

When i add a new project in Visual Studio it does not get added to the solution file
Before it was working but recently having a issue. In the file location project displaying but in VS its not displaying. Have i changed any settings

[image]

Comment: When i create a new Web Application project also getting the same issue

Comment: please visit link below I hope it can help you:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772243/visual-studio-not-showing-all-projects-in-solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772243/visual-studio-not-showing-all-projects-in-solution)

Comment: Thanks i had an error in the json file where the sdk version was mentioned wrong