# Visual Studio Crashes When Opening Project

Tags: visual-studio-2013

my project has stopped loading - Visual Studio 2013 just crashes and I'm really worried I wont be able to continue my work on the project solution. I've found this error in Visual Studio's Activity Log, but I don't really know what it means, can anyone help?

Visual Studio **does** open on it's own, but I cant run the project solution I've been working on.

```
    <record>818</record>
    <time>2015/04/03 14:42:01.839</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{E269B994-EF71-4CE0-8BCD-581C217372E8}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>819</record>
    <time>2015/04/03 14:42:01.839</time>
    <type>Warning</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Unexpected system error mode before loading package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage]</description>
    <guid>{E269B994-EF71-4CE0-8BCD-581C217372E8}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>820</record>
    <time>2015/04/03 14:42:01.839</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage]</description>
    <guid>{E269B994-EF71-4CE0-8BCD-581C217372E8}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>821</record>
    <time>2015/04/03 14:42:02.158</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage]</description>
    <guid>{E269B994-EF71-4CE0-8BCD-581C217372E8}</guid>
    <hr>80131500</hr>
    <errorinfo>No exports were found that match the constraint: 
    ContractName    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.IContentTypeRegistryService
    RequiredTypeIdentity    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.IContentTypeRegistryService</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>822</record>
    <time>2015/04/03 14:42:02.160</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage]</description>
    <guid>{E269B994-EF71-4CE0-8BCD-581C217372E8}</guid>
    <hr>80131500</hr>
    <errorinfo>No exports were found that match the constraint: 
    ContractName    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.IContentTypeRegistryService
    RequiredTypeIdentity    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.IContentTypeRegistryService</errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error message "No exports were found that match the constraint contract name"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try [clearing the Visual Studio component model cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17604007/4342563).