# show error message when create new project in Visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

[image: Show following dialogue box when create a new project]

I am using a Microsoft VS professional 2012.
Operating system is Windows 7 Professional N

When ever I click on new project, "VS" ask for the location then after providing the exact location as I click on OK ! it shows the attached message dialogue box !

Comment: This isssue is also get resolved from ---http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name

Comment: the above problem is solved from the hints given at :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name