# Visual Studio shows only attach and no run with PTVS RC

Tags: visual-studio, ptvs

I downloaded PTVS RC today and installed it. After restarting VS, there was an error about importing Python Tools that said the following and solutions were not being loaded:

```
No exports were found that match the constraint
```

Based on this post [here at SO,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name) i renamed my ComponentModelCache file. Now although VS loads old solutions, all I see is an Attach button and no Run/Debug button. For new projects, it works fine. I am using Visual Studio 2013 Professional Edition. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the issue is not with PTVS RC. Although I had only 1 project in my solution, all I had to do was set the startup Project. This can be done by right-clicking on the solution. Once the startup project is set, the solution is good to run.