# Visual Studio 2013 Aborting When Opening Property Sheets for Project

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I don't know when this started, but I discovered that Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 aborts when attempting to open properties for a project within a solution. It seems to only happen when we have more than one project in the solution.

I've been able to reproduce it in two circumstances:

- The first project is C++ and the second project is Fortran. Right-clicking on the first project and selecting Properties crashes Visual Studio without a crash dump or any kind of pop-up notification. Visual Studio just ceases to exist. Right-clicking on the Fortran project brings up the property sheet without any problem.
- The second circumstance is with two projects, both C++. In this case, I'm able to open properties successfully for the first project, but not for the second one.

In every case I've tried where there's a one-to-one solution and project, it's working fine. A colleague who's working with VS 2013 Update 4 verified that the crash occurs for him as well.

We don't know when this started, but historically, we've opened these property sheets many, many times. However, it's probably been a few months since I've worked on a mixed-language process, and same with my colleague.

I've turned on logging and there was a complaint in the log about two versions of the Desktop SDK having the same internal ID. I removed one of those altogether, but that didn't seem to affect anything. It's also not clear if that error has any relationship to the crash.

I've also done a repair on Visual Studio, and that did not correct the problem.

I've also tried deleting the .suo and .user files. Again, no luck.

I've done quite a bit of googling but haven't found anything that matches this specific problem.

Any ideas?

Thank you,
Doug

Comment: I found this, which corrected the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name/17604007#17604007

Comment: Thank god! You saved me!