# visual studio 2013 crashes when opening a file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, crash, windows-10

I could work without any problem in my C# projects. Today suddenly all attempts to open a file within VS cause an error (total crash, VS tries to find a solution, restart of VS, problem still there). The loading of the solution seems to be OK...

I did a lot of research but could not find a solution yet. What I tried is:

- System reboot (of course ;-)  )
- Check for Updates (running Win10, everything up to date)
- Create a brand new project (same error)
- Try different file types (xml, cs, dataset, ... same error)
- read ActivityLog.xml (found errors concerning EditorPackages)

This is the most telling entry in ActivityLog:

```
  <entry>
    <record>593</record>
    <time>2015/11/03 20:34:29.514</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage]</description>
    <guid>{E269B994-EF71-4CE0-8BCD-581C217372E8}</guid>
    <hr>80070057 - E_INVALIDARG</hr>
    <errorinfo>No EditorOptionDefinition export found for the given option name: Graphics/Simple/Enable
Parameter name: optionId</errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

Some people suggested to delete or rename a folder named `ComponentModelCache` but I cannot find such a folder (if I'm not wrong it should be in the same folder as the ActivityLog).

So it has to do with the EditorPackage (seems to be obvious as I get the error when trying to edit a file...)

Please show me a way to repair my VS! Thx!

Comment: VS13... I stopped using it and reverted to 2012 because of crazy things it does

Comment: a simple google search of the exact error would have led you to the following http://www.rajapet.com/2014/02/when-the-editorpackage-does-not-load-correctly.html

Comment: @T.S. I'm using it for about 4 months with really big projects and did not find many problems (up to now...)

Comment: @MethodMan, I was there, know this page... As I wrote above: I do not see any folder called ComponentModelCache in the given place :-(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name do a google search on this as well ... `where to locate the ComponentModelCache folder`

Comment: @MethodMan, this could've been really helpful, have to try it. Its weird: I was exactly there, entered the folder name manually and got the message "no such folder". But with the full path of the question you mention the folder is there... Strange... Anyway. I'll check this. Please state this as an answer and I'll vote it up and - if it solves my problem - will of course accept it.

Comment: @Shnugo I can't state that as an answer because it's just a link to another Stackoverflow post. not sure if that really counts as an answer in this case.

Comment: @MethodMan. This must count as an answer because it really solved my problem. Thank you very much! Believe me: I'm not the one who cries for help immediately. I was looking around for hours. Please let this be an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Shnugo I have posted it as an answer glad I was able to help you quickly find a working solution.. cheers..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I believe that links do not count as answers along based on your request to add it as an answer since it helped you to solve your problem you can find many different solutions based on previous answers and suggestions located here

[where to locate the ComponentModelCache folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name)