# Oracle Developer Tools for VS2013 throwing object reference error

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, ado.net

I have the following installed:

VS 2013
Oracle 11g database
Oracle Developer Tools for VS 2013 12.1.2400
ODP.NET 12.1.2400
EF 6

After I add or select a new connection when adding a new ADO.NET Entity Data Model, I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error and am not able to add a new model.

[image: Error screen shot]

This was previously working when I had the DevArt Oracle client installed (although I wasn't using it). After I uninstalled the DevArt components I started to get this error.

I have since uninstalled and re-installed the Oracle developer tools and ODP.NET but still get the same error.

I am able to connect to the Oracle database via the Server Explorer within VS.

Any ideas? It's driving me mad.

Comment: Which architecture did you install?  32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: I originally had installed 64 bit, and everything was working until I uninstalled the Devart component I was no longer using. I've tried to reinstall the 64 bit version with the same error. I have also uninstalled everything and tried the 32 bit version and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to give up on VS 2013 and installed VS 2015 which I was planning on doing anyway.

In VS 2015 I got the same "Object reference error" when trying to add a new project. I found this thread: [Error message "No exports were found that match the constraint contract name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name/17604007#17604007) which had the solution for that.

I installed the Oracle Developer Tools for VS 2015 (the MSI version) and it's working. Still not working in VS 2013, but I will just abandon it.

I suspect uninstalling the Devart component caused this issue.

Comment: Strange, usually DevArt installation should not touch any Oracle items.