# Visual Studio 2015: Multiple package load error after Update 3 failure: Windows 10

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Update: I fixed it. See answer below - [Visual Studio 2015: Multiple package load error after Update 3 failure: Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717145/visual-studio-2015-multiple-package-load-error-after-update-3-failure-windows/38718731#38718731)

So that's that.

1. Visual Studio 2015 with Update 2 was installed on Windows 8 64 bit.
   Everything was working well and good.
2. Windows 8 was upgraded to Windows 10. Visual Studio still worked, no issues.
3. While adding ClickOnce tool via setup, Update 3 got installed as well.
   Everything went and hit the proverbial fan.

Activity log XML is as below:

```
461 ERROR Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.143 
462 ERROR Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.143 
463 ERROR Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.143 
464 ERROR Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.143 
465 ERROR Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.143 
466 ERROR Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.143 
467 ERROR Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.144 
468 ERROR Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.144 
469 ERROR Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.144 
470 ERROR Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.144 
471 ERROR Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.144 
472 ERROR Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.144 
473 ERROR Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.144 
474 ERROR Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.152 
475 ERROR Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.152 
476 ERROR Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.152 
477 ERROR Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.152 
478 ERROR Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.152 
479 ERROR Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.152 
480 ERROR Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.152 
481 ERROR Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.154 
482 ERROR Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.154 
483 ERROR Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.155 
484 ERROR Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.155 
485 ERROR Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.155 
486 ERROR Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.155 
487 ERROR Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.155 
488 ERROR Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.155 
489 ERROR Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.155 
490 ERROR Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.155 
491 ERROR Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.156 
492 ERROR Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.156 
493 ERROR Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.156 
494 ERROR Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.156 
495 ERROR Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.156 
496 ERROR Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.156 
497 ERROR Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.156 
498 ERROR Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.156 
499 ERROR Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.156 
500 ERROR Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.156 
501 ERROR Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.156 
502 ERROR Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version   Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage 2016/08/02 09:38:18.157 
503  Done loading new toolbox content, total time = 265 ms
```

Comment: I had the same problem today and your fixed worked (tyvm), but the issue developed only after a bunch of windows updates were installed this week. Update 3 had been installed for some time, and I am still running windows 7 so the cause here may be different.

Comment: Could be. Thanks for your comment. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have finally solved it.

Performed about 3 repairs, 4 uninstalls and reinstalls already before posting this question. Read couple of suggestions from another post on stackoverflow, and finally did the following:

Deleted ComponentModelCache folder and run Visual Studio. That's it.

> Find “C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0 folder and
>   delete the ComponentModelCache folder.

You have to completely delete the ComponentModelCache folder. Take backup if you want.

Comment: Here's instructions on clearing it for other VS versions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17604007/1703887