# Xamarin axml error

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I have an error when I'm trying to open the asmxl file from a Xamarin project in VS2015 Community. The error reads:

No exports were found that match the constraint:
ContractName VisualStudioWorkspace
RequiresTypeIdentity Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspace

I tried clearing the cache, reinstalling VS2015, Repair VS2015, Run devenv /setup, installing xamarin manually, adding workspace extensions, ect. Well, that is what I can remember from the past 2 days.

It would seem that this particular problem about Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspace is not well documented as the general error every body is complaining about is:"The operation could not be completed."

Any ideas or pointers would be most welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error message "No exports were found that match the constraint contract name"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name)

Answer (score 0):

So, I thought I'd post what I've done at the end of the day. 
I'm pretty tired of Microshaft Winblows and their nonsense, it seems to get more by the day and not less, so I just bit the bullet and started with Android studio and Java. 
It wasn't as big of a mountain to climb as I thought it would be. In like 2 weeks I could do GPS, HTTP POST/GET, Barcode scanning, pictures, SQLite(ships with Android).
If you have this issue, just cross over. It is not as bad as you might think.