# Dealing with Invisible Code and how to get it back

Tags: invisible

I can't seem to find my code anywhere, there were solutions to my question. Such as checking the 'Solution Explorer' However accessing the 'Solution Explorer' didn't help, because I couldn't pull it up either.

Is there any other way to access my file?

Comment: there are 2 answers, both of which from last year. Answering questions doesn't require rep as far as I know and please don't ask questions without them actually being a question. If you are going to ask a duplicate question, indicate that you know the original and say why the answers that have been posted there didn't work for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio 2015 - Can't see code to existing project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39600820/visual-studio-2015-cant-see-code-to-existing-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem by going to the 'View' tab and selecting the 'Object Brower', select the name of your file. Press the drop down arrows until you see something called 'Program'. When you click on program, you should see some method/functions from your project. Double click on any of those and VS should bring up your code.

[Object Brower](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXBsB.png)

[Name of File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IU03w.png)

Comment: Had troubles posting this, I had to type in the answer in the question to get past the error message that my question title wasn't good enough. That was a lie. I then edited it out, and into the answer. Please fix this.

Comment: I cannot put the correct title of this post because the site refuses to accept my changes. Again please fix this.