# VS 2013 Error-"No exports were found that match the constraint:"

Tags: visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 10, Today I am getting error "No exports were found that match the constraint:"

I did following but still having same issue:

1. Solution giving in link
   [Error message "No exports were found that match the constraint contract name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name)

by removing/renaming "ComponentModelCache" folder, but still problem.

2. Run VS Repair, but still having same problem.
3. Finally, I Uninstalled Visual Studio 2013 and reinstalled, but still having 
   same problem.

Please suggest what do do now?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I did find answer myself, instead of deleting/renaming 'ComponentModelCache' folder in path
C:\Users\'username'\AppData\local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0

I renamed folder 'Microsoft' in path
C:\Users\'username'\AppData\local\

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name) more solutions which require deleting the cache in %APPDATA%.

In my case, the problem was that I was initializing and using class with the MEF framework but didn't declare the class as a MEF class.

How to import a MEF class:

```
[Import(typeof(ICalculator))]  
public ICalculator calculator;
```

How to define and export a MEF class:

```
public interface ICalculator  
{  
     String Calculate(String input);  
}  

[Export(typeof(ICalculator))]  
class MySimpleCalculator : ICalculator  
{
}
```

The code example is taken from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for contributing to an old "answered" thread. however for me, using Win 10, VS 2013. I had to remove the 'ComponentModelCache' folder from each version of VS that I had installed before this issue was resolved.