# Exception: No exports were found that match the constraint contract name: Nuget.VisualStudio.IVsPackageInstaller

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

In Visual Studio 2010 alone installed machine, **IVsPackageInstaller** API throws the below exception while installing the NuGet.

`Exception: No exports were found that match the constraint contract name: Nuget.VisualStudio.IVsPackageInstaller.`

I tried all the solutions reported in the following links. But nothing worked.

[Error message "No exports were found that match the constraint contract name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name)

[VS 2013 Error-"No exports were found that match the constraint:"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215010/vs-2013-error-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint)

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zxue/2015/01/02/fix-visual-studio-error-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint/

[Error in Visual Studio 2013: "No exports were found that match the constraint"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847640/error-in-visual-studio-2013-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint)

Awaiting for your valuable response !!!!.