# Microsoft Visual Studio not opening files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Whenever I try opening a .cs file with Visual Studio, I get this error :

Expected 1 export(s) with contract name "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.IContentTypeRegistryService" but found 0 after 
applying applicable constraints.

Visual Studio had been working working fine for me, then all of a sudden this started happening. I tried deleting the cache and even uninstalling the program altogether, but the error persists. I checked online everywhere, but nobody seems to have had this issue before. [Here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w23aP.png).

Comment: Is it any .cs file or a specific one? Also is this I. The context of an open solution or is it being opened standalone?

Comment: Its just a regular .cs file. I've tried with multiple ones, but it didn't work for any of them. I'm kind of new to C# and I don't know too much about it, what do you mean by open solution or standalone?

Comment: "Visual Studio was working fine" - does it work fine when working with vb? How long has it been working fine for? Can you list software versions? Are you working on a project or are you using VS to open individual files without them being part of a project?

Comment: It doesn't work with vb. I got Visual Studio 4 days ago and it had been working fine until yesterday when this error started popping up. I haven't tampered with the files at all. I use Visual Studio 2015 (The most recent version) and I use it to open individual files.

Comment: The best SO link I've found gives heaps of different options - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name - I would suggest running a repair on the install and things other than clearing the cache.

Answer (score 0):

The best SO link I've found gives heaps of different options - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name) - I would suggest running a repair on the install and try things other than clearing the cache.

The referenced link indicates a bunch of different conditions that affect how you resolve the issue. For example are you running express/community edition or professional etc?

Without knowing what causes the cache to get corrupted I can't answer exactly how to fix it.