# When I create a new website in visual studio 2012, I got this error

Tags: asp.net

[When I create a new website in visual studio 2012, I got this error...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K645G.png)

No exports were found that match the constraint:

ContractName
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.ITextDocumentFactoryService
RequiredTypeIdentity
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.ITextDocumentFactoryService

Please tell me how to fix this error???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to rename or delete the ComponentModelCache in your local folder.

[image]

Comment: I tried it but I didn't found the folder %AppData% in my directory C:\Users\{UserName}....so please give me another solution...