# How to make Unity open Visual Studio 2017 to edit code

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Basically every time i try to open a c# file from unity i get:

message "one or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly. please see the output window for details"

followed by "An exception has been encountered. This may be casued by an extension. you can get more information by examining the file ..." This file is really long so I will paste the errors only:

> 568    ERROR   LegacySitePackage failed for package [CSharpPackage]Source: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices' Description: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=2.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=2.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=2.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.LanguageService.AbstractPackage`2.Initialize() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.CSharp.LanguageService.CSharpPackage.Initialize() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp) WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].     {13C3BBB4-F18F-4111-9F54-A0FB010D9194}  80070002    VisualStudio    2019/04/08 11:04:50.397
>
> 569    ERROR   SetSite failed for package CSharpPackage    {13C3BBB4-F18F-4111-9F54-A0FB010D9194}  80070002    VisualStudio    2019/04/08 11:04:50.403
>
> 570    ERROR   End package load [CSharpPackage]    {13C3BBB4-F18F-4111-9F54-A0FB010D9194}  80070002    VisualStudio    2019/04/08 11:04:50.408
>
> 574    ERROR   LegacySitePackage failed for package [CSharpPackage]Source: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices' Description: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=2.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=2.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=2.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.LanguageService.AbstractPackage`2.Initialize() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.CSharp.LanguageService.CSharpPackage.Initialize() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp) WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].     {13C3BBB4-F18F-4111-9F54-A0FB010D9194}  80070002    VisualStudio    2019/04/08 11:04:50.413
>
> 575    ERROR   SetSite failed for package CSharpPackage    {13C3BBB4-F18F-4111-9F54-A0FB010D9194}  80070002    VisualStudio    2019/04/08 11:04:50.413
>
> 576    ERROR   End package load [CSharpPackage]    {13C3BBB4-F18F-4111-9F54-A0FB010D9194}  80070002    VisualStudio    2019/04/08 11:04:50.413
>
> 614    ERROR   LegacySitePackage failed for package [CSharpPackage]Source: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices' Description: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=2.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=2.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=2.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.LanguageService.AbstractPackage`2.Initialize() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.CSharp.LanguageService.CSharpPackage.Initialize() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp) WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].     {13C3BBB4-F18F-4111-9F54-A0FB010D9194}  80070002    VisualStudio    2019/04/08 11:04:51.586
>
> 615    ERROR   SetSite failed for package CSharpPackage    {13C3BBB4-F18F-4111-9F54-A0FB010D9194}  80070002    VisualStudio    2019/04/08 11:04:51.592
>
> 616    ERROR   End package load [CSharpPackage]    {13C3BBB4-F18F-4111-9F54-A0FB010D9194}  80070002    VisualStudio    2019/04/08 11:04:51.596
>
> 641    ERROR   Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID 'Microsoft.Windows.DevelopmentKit.Desktop' is already loaded at C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\10\DESKTOP SDK...
>             C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\8.1\DESKTOP SDK\         Extension Manager   2019/04/08 11:04:51.967
>
> 642    ERROR   Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID 'Microsoft.Windows.DevelopmentKit.WindowsStore' is already loaded at C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\10\WINDOWS STORE SDK...
>             C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\8.1\WINDOWS STORE SDK\           Extension Manager   2019/04/08 11:04:51.968
>
> 661    ERROR   A MEF Component threw an exception at runtime: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.CompositionFailedException: An exception was thrown while initializing part "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.DiagnosticService". ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=2.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.DiagnosticService..ctor(IAsynchronousOperationListenerProvider listenerProvider) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.CreateValue() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.Create() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.b__0()            Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.VsShellComponentModelHost 2019/04/08 11:04:53.135
>
> 662    ERROR   A MEF Component threw an exception at runtime: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.CompositionFailedException: An exception was thrown while initializing part "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.DiagnosticService". ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=2.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.DiagnosticService..ctor(IAsynchronousOperationListenerProvider listenerProvider) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.CreateValue() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.Create() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.b__0() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetValueForImportElement(RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, RuntimeImport import, RuntimeExport export, Func`3 lazyFactory) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetValueForImportSite(RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, RuntimeImport import) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.<CreateValue>b__10_0(RuntimeImport import) at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.CreateValue() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.Create() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.b__0()            Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.VsShellComponentModelHost 2019/04/08 11:04:53.140
>
> 711    ERROR   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.CompositionFailedException: An exception was thrown while initializing part "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.DiagnosticService". ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=2.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.DiagnosticService..ctor(IAsynchronousOperationListenerProvider listenerProvider) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.CreateValue() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.Create() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.b__0() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetValueForImportElement(RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, RuntimeImport import, RuntimeExport export, Func`3 lazyFactory) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetValueForImportSite(RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, RuntimeImport import) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.<CreateValue>b__10_0(RuntimeImport import) at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.CreateValue() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.Create() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<GetExportedValueHelper>b__0() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.DelegateServices.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`1.b__0() at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() at System.Lazy`1.get_Value() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.Implementation.TagAggregator`1.GatherTaggers(ITextBuffer textBuffer)           Editor or Editor Extension

>

I have uninstalled reinstalled visual studio compenents, updated unity and created a new projects in unity, deleted files and folders and other stuff by

following this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/getting-started-with-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?view=vs-2017

and this: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/8536/unexpected-system-error-mode-before-loading-packag.html

and this: [Error message "No exports were found that match the constraint contract name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name/17604007#17604007)

​and this: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1243747/visual-studio-error.html

The output window error details is: "C:...\unity\f1febc1088bcc6547ad7f93828b356f1\sprint 02\Assembly-CSharp.csproj : error  : Project 'Assembly-CSharp' could not be opened because the Visual C# 2017 compiler could not be created. Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."

i am running visual studio enterprise 2017 version 15.9.11 and

unity version 2018.3.11f1 personal.

microsoft visual studio tools for unity 3.9.0.3 is enabled

Comment: if you are following  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/getting-started-with-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?view=vs-2017 then you will have Visual studio community version. Try to change it from inside unity's preference settings.

Comment: What components of VS did you install? Have you run VS outside unity? are you sure its not just sitting on the window saying how do you want to configure VS?

Comment: Saad - in Preferrences - External Tools the options I have are "open by File Extension", "Visual Studio 2017" or "Browse". BugFinder - I went to Visual Studio installer - modify - workloads and unchecked "Game Development with unity" clicked and clicked modify. After modification I went back in and checked "Game dev..." and modify. VS works fine when I use it on its own e.g. open it and then write code in C# or C++. The error windows in VS are informatitve and don't appear to be asking me how to configure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled VS enterprise and installed VS community. I was then able to open VS via unity to edit code. I wondered why it should make a difference between VS enterprise and community, so I uninstalled community and reinstalled enterprise. And .... it worked. So to recap: Uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio fixed my issue.