# Why doesn't the c++ file run in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, build-error

So I tried making a basic game on the console using screen buffers, I was able to create it and make a square move in the canvas, but for my next project I looked up a website with the ASCII characters and pasted a couple into a comment at the end of the c++ file, when I ran the file visual studio prompted: [image: visual studio prompt]

I clicked yes and it didn't run anymore.
Also I recently have installed an extension for visual studio (before it didn't run, the extension works fine but I don't know if the extension may have caused this as I didn't tried running it with the extension downloaded and applied), when I open visual studio and open a file it says:
[image: vs file open]

The last record in the `ActivityLog` xml file, has a type of error and it's description is:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.CompositionFailedException: Expected 1 export(s) with contract name "Microsoft.VisualStudio.CppSvc.Internal.CodeAnalysis.ICodeAnalysisService" but found 0 after applying applicable constraints.
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExports(ImportDefinition importDefinition)
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExports[T,TMetadataView](String contractName, ImportCardinality cardinality)
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExport[T,TMetadataView](String contractName)
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExport[T](String contractName)
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExportT
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExportedValueT
>    at  Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.ComponentModel.GetServiceT
>    at  Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.ManagedInterop.<>c.<Initialize>b__52_15()
>    at
>   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
>    at
>   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
>    at
>   System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.CodeAnalysis.ResultTaggerProvider.CreateTagger[T](ITextBuffer buffer)
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.Implementation.TagAggregator`1.GatherTaggers(ITextBuffer textBuffer)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)

I have Visual Studio 2017
So why does running the file (with the local windows debugger button) say that there were build errors? And how can I fix it?
When it prompts the build error, and I click no it usually shows the errors but in this case it doesn't, yes will just run the last "successful" build (although I haven't changed the file since I have finished it before this error message started popping up)
Also there is no error in my code as I was able to run it before the build error kept appearing and I haven't touched the file since(only now to show the problems are)

Thanks for your time! if anything was unclear because of my English, comment and I'll try to clarify it

Comment: What are the build errors? Can you edit the exact error message into your question? Can you also include an example of the lines the errors are on, maybe with a few lines context around them?

Comment: I'd also suggest resaving the file as UTF-8 in case that makes a difference (in case your extension is failing to parse a UTF16 file), or identifying and removing the non-ASCII characters and going back to the default codepage.

Comment: _"...website with the ASCII characters ..."_ nope you pasted Unicode.  Don't put these in your source files put them in an external file instead and read them in.  Be careful on MS-Windows using UTF-8 as Windows is native UTF-16 (UTF-8 is possible with some extra work).

Comment: @Rup There are no errors as I wrote in my question no lines are red and when I click no when it prompts because of build error  It doesn't show the errors when in other projects it should.
I have already removed the extension but that didn't fix it

Comment: OK. Can you check the Output tab? If there’s nothing there, can you try building the project from a Visual Studio command prompt? There must be some output.

Comment: @Rup it only says Object reference not set to an instance of an object which is weird considering there were no errors yesterday and I haven't edited this file since then,
also I have tested creating a new console project, leaving it as it is and running it with only a `std::cout` gives the same output

Comment: That’s a runtime error not a compile time error - you’ve hit a bug in the compiler or build system or Visual Studio then. I’d roll back to yesterday’s version of the code then if you have a commit, else I’d copy and paste this into a new file without the new lines - retype them rather than copy and paste - and don’t save as Unicode.

Comment: @Rup I've created a new file just to see if it would work, included iostream, created the main function, std::cout -ed "test" and returned 0 it says the same thing, I think the problem isn't with the code I have also tried resetting all of my settings to default using the built in tool for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the error by deleting ComponentModelChache folder located at:

```
C:\Users\%userName%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0
```

15.0 is the version of your visual studio so it varies depending on the version you're using, `%userName%` is a replacement for the user you're logged in as

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me too. But VisualStudio needed to be restarted after deleting the cache.
For the same problem see this topic also [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name)